# How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days

Tags: t-sql, datediff

What would be the best way to calculate someone's age in years, months, and days in T-SQL (SQL Server 2000)?

The `datediff` function doesn't handle year boundaries well, plus getting the months and days separate will be a bear.  I know I can do it on the client side relatively easily, but I'd like to have it done in my [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure).

Comment: Please see [this answer to a javascript age question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11479533/57611) that discusses how difficult it is to come up with a human-sensible way of choosing years, months, and days. I will excerpt in my next comment.

Comment: "If you calculate Feb 2 to Mar 2 as one month, then it's 1 month 29 days. But what if it were Jan 2 to Mar 1? That's the same number of days elapsed between them. Is that now 1 month (for all of April) + 1 day in March + the 31 days in Jan for 1 month 32 days? Do you want your months to coincide to a physical calendar so a human could back track with his finger and get the correct date out of it? That is much harder than you think."

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here is some T-SQL that gives you the number of years, months, and days since the day specified in @date.  It takes into account the fact that DATEDIFF() computes the difference without considering what month or day it is (so the month diff between 8/31 and 9/1 is 1 month) and handles that with a case statement that decrements the result where appropriate.

```
DECLARE @date datetime, @tmpdate datetime, @years int, @months int, @days int
SELECT @date = '2/29/04'

SELECT @tmpdate = @date

SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(@date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate)
SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(m, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(m, @months, @tmpdate)
SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(d, @tmpdate, GETDATE())

SELECT @years, @months, @days
```

Comment: Above comment with shortened syntax is wrong; requires separate check for month greater, then if month same do day check

Comment: Yeah, the shortened syntax doesn't work right if the current date is the 30th of the month and the date being evaluated is the 1st of a subsequent month.

Comment: whats the reason for the temporary date variable? both @@tmpdate and @@date are used in 2 of the expressions. is this expected to do something different than if just one was used?

Comment: @rdans the best reason why the @@tmpdate variable is used at all is so that at the end of this code, we still know what our input date was.  It might seem pedantic but without knowing how and where the code would be copied and pasted, I wanted whoever used this code to be able to reference the original input @@date variable for whatever reason.  You could optimize the code by removing @@tmpdate, so long as your code didn't need to remember the original value.

Answer (score 16):

Try this...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
 (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend) , @datestart) > @dateend)
THEN DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend) -1
ELSE DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend)
END
```

Basically the "DateDiff( year...", gives you the age the person will turn this year, so i have just add a case statement to say, if they have not had a birthday yet this year, then subtract 1 year, else return the value.

Comment: This is useful if you only need the years since that date.

Comment: Somewhat shorter version `SELECT DATEDIFF(year, @datestart ,@dateend) + CASE WHEN (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend) , @datestart) > @dateend) THEN - 1 ELSE 0 END`

Answer (score 13):

Simple way to get age as text is as below:

```
Select cast((DATEDIFF(m, date_of_birth, GETDATE())/12) as varchar) + ' Y & ' + 
       cast((DATEDIFF(m, date_of_birth, GETDATE())%12) as varchar) + ' M' as Age
```

Results Format will be:

```
**63 Y & 2 M**
```

Answer (score 5):

### Implemented by arithmetic with ISO formatted date.

```
declare @now date,@dob date, @now_i int,@dob_i int, @days_in_birth_month int
declare @years int, @months int, @days int
set @now = '2013-02-28' 
set @dob = '2012-02-29' -- Date of Birth

set @now_i = convert(varchar(8),@now,112) -- iso formatted: 20130228
set @dob_i = convert(varchar(8),@dob,112) -- iso formatted: 20120229
set @years = ( @now_i - @dob_i)/10000
-- (20130228 - 20120229)/10000 = 0 years

set @months =(1200 + (month(@now)- month(@dob))*100 + day(@now) - day(@dob))/100 %12
-- (1200 + 0228 - 0229)/100 % 12 = 11 months

set @days_in_birth_month = day(dateadd(d,-1,left(convert(varchar(8),dateadd(m,1,@dob),112),6)+'01'))
set @days = (sign(day(@now) - day(@dob))+1)/2 * (day(@now) - day(@dob))
          + (sign(day(@dob) - day(@now))+1)/2 * (@days_in_birth_month - day(@dob) + day(@now))
-- ( (-1+1)/2*(28 - 29) + (1+1)/2*(29 - 29 + 28))
-- Explain: if the days of now is bigger than the days of birth, then diff the two days
--          else add the days of now and the distance from the date of birth to the end of the birth month 
select @years,@months,@days -- 0, 11, 28
```

### Test Cases

*The approach of days is different from the accepted answer, the differences shown in the comments below:*

```
       dob        now  years  months  days 
2012-02-29 2013-02-28      0      11    28  --Days will be 30 if calculated by the approach in accepted answer. 
2012-02-29 2016-02-28      3      11    28  --Days will be 31 if calculated by the approach in accepted answer, since the day of birth will be changed to 28 from 29 after dateadd by years. 
2012-02-29 2016-03-31      4       1     2
2012-01-30 2016-02-29      4       0    30
2012-01-30 2016-03-01      4       1     2  --Days will be 1 if calculated by the approach in accepted answer, since the day of birth will be changed to 30 from 29 after dateadd by years.
2011-12-30 2016-02-29      4       1    30
```

### An short version of Days by case statement:

```
set @days = CASE WHEN day(@now) >= day(@dob) THEN day(@now) - day(@dob)
                 ELSE @days_in_birth_month - day(@dob) + day(@now) END
```

**If you want the age of years and months only, it could be simpler**

```
set @years = ( @now_i/100 - @dob_i/100)/100
set @months =(12 + month(@now) - month(@dob))%12 
select @years,@months -- 1, 0
```

**NOTE:** A very useful link of [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a (slightly) simpler version:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CalculateAge 
    @dayOfBirth datetime
AS

DECLARE @today datetime, @thisYearBirthDay datetime
DECLARE @years int, @months int, @days int

SELECT @today = GETDATE()

SELECT @thisYearBirthDay = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @dayOfBirth, @today), @dayOfBirth)

SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(year, @dayOfBirth, @today) - (CASE WHEN @thisYearBirthDay > @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

SELECT @months = MONTH(@today - @thisYearBirthDay) - 1

SELECT @days = DAY(@today - @thisYearBirthDay) - 1

SELECT @years, @months, @days
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

The same sort of thing as a function.

```
create function [dbo].[Age](@dayOfBirth datetime, @today datetime)
   RETURNS varchar(100)
AS

Begin
DECLARE @thisYearBirthDay datetime
DECLARE @years int, @months int, @days int

set @thisYearBirthDay = DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, @dayOfBirth, @today), @dayOfBirth)
set @years = DATEDIFF(year, @dayOfBirth, @today) - (CASE WHEN @thisYearBirthDay > @today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
set @months = MONTH(@today - @thisYearBirthDay) - 1
set @days = DAY(@today - @thisYearBirthDay) - 1

return cast(@years as varchar(2)) + ' years,' + cast(@months as varchar(2)) + ' months,' + cast(@days as varchar(3)) + ' days'
end
```

Comment: SELECT dbo.age('2013-03-31', '2014-01-31') returns 10m2d.

Answer (score 2):

```
create  procedure getDatedifference

(
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
)
as
begin
    declare @monthToShow int
    declare @dayToShow int

    --set @startdate='01/21/1934'
    --set @enddate=getdate()

    if (DAY(@startdate) > DAY(@enddate))
        begin
            set @dayToShow=0

            if (month(@startdate) > month(@enddate))
                begin
                    set @monthToShow=  (12-month(@startdate)+ month(@enddate)-1)
                end
            else if (month(@startdate) < month(@enddate))
                begin
                    set @monthToShow=  ((month(@enddate)-month(@startdate))-1)
                end
            else
               begin
                   set @monthToShow=  11
               end
            -- set @monthToShow= convert(int, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,@enddate)- DATEDIFF(dd,0,@startdate),0)))-((convert(int,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate) / 365.25))*12))-1
                         if(@monthToShow<0)
                         begin
                            set @monthToShow=0
                         end

                      declare @amonthbefore integer
                      set @amonthbefore=Month(@enddate)-1
                          if(@amonthbefore=0)
                             begin
                                set @amonthbefore=12
                              end


                      if (@amonthbefore  in(1,3,5,7,8,10,12))
                          begin
                            set @dayToShow=31-DAY(@startdate)+DAY(@enddate)
                          end
                      if (@amonthbefore=2)
                         begin
                           IF (YEAR( @enddate ) % 4 = 0 AND YEAR( @enddate ) % 100 != 0) OR  YEAR( @enddate ) % 400 = 0
                                 begin
                                    set @dayToShow=29-DAY(@startdate)+DAY(@enddate)
                                  end
                           else
                               begin
                                   set @dayToShow=28-DAY(@startdate)+DAY(@enddate)
                           end
                      end
                      if (@amonthbefore in (4,6,9,11))
                        begin
                           set @dayToShow=30-DAY(@startdate)+DAY(@enddate)
                        end
                 end
    else
        begin
          --set @monthToShow=convert(int, DATEDIFF(mm,0,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,@enddate)- DATEDIFF(dd,0,@startdate),0)))-((convert(int,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate) / 365.25))*12))
          if (month(@enddate)< month(@startdate))
              begin
                 set @monthToShow=12+(month(@enddate)-month(@startdate))
              end
          else
              begin
                set @monthToShow= (month(@enddate)-month(@startdate))
              end
          set @dayToShow=DAY(@enddate)-DAY(@startdate)
        end

    SELECT
        FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate) / 365.25) as [yearToShow],
          @monthToShow as  monthToShow ,@dayToShow as dayToShow ,
        convert(varchar,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate) / 365.25)) +' Year ' + convert(varchar,@monthToShow) +' months '+convert(varchar,@dayToShow)+' days ' as age

    return
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this Function I modified (the Days part) From @Dane answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720/2097023

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.EdadAMD
    (
        @FECHA DATETIME
    )
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(10)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
            @tmpdate DATETIME
          , @years   INT
          , @months  INT
          , @days    INT
          , @EdadAMD NVARCHAR(10);

        SELECT @tmpdate = @FECHA;

        SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE
                                          WHEN (MONTH(@FECHA) >    MONTH(GETDATE()))
                                             OR (
                                                MONTH(@FECHA) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                                          AND DAY(@FECHA) > DAY(GETDATE())
                                          ) THEN
                                                1
                                            ELSE
                                                0
                                    END;
    SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate);
    SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(m, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE
                              WHEN DAY(@FECHA) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN
                                                            1
                                                        ELSE
                                                            0
                                                    END;
    SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(m, @months, @tmpdate);

    IF MONTH(@FECHA) = MONTH(GETDATE())
       AND DAY(@FECHA) > DAY(GETDATE())
          SELECT @days = 
            DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) - (DAY(@FECHA) - DAY(GETDATE()));
    ELSE
        SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(d, @tmpdate, GETDATE());

    SELECT @EdadAMD = CONCAT(@years, 'a', @months, 'm', @days, 'd');

    RETURN @EdadAMD;

END; 
GO
```

It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the question several times with results outputting Years, Month, Days but never a numeric / decimal result. (At least not one that doesn't round incorrectly).
I welcome feedback on this function.  Might not still need a little adjusting.

-- Input to the function is two dates.
-- Output is the numeric number of years between the two dates in Decimal(7,4) format.
-- Output is always always a possitive number.

### -- NOTE:Output does not handle if difference is greater than 999.9999

-- Logic is based on three steps.
-- 1) Is the difference less than 1 year (0.5000, 0.3333, 0.6667, ect.)
-- 2) Is the difference exactly a whole number of years (1,2,3, ect.)

### -- 3) (Else)...The difference is years and some number of days. (1.5000, 2.3333, 7.6667, ect.)

---

---

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[F_Get_Actual_Age](@pi_date1 datetime,@pi_date2 datetime)
RETURNS Numeric(7,4)
AS
BEGIN

Declare 
 @l_tmp_date    DATETIME
,@l_days1       DECIMAL(9,6)
,@l_days2       DECIMAL(9,6)
,@l_result      DECIMAL(10,6)
,@l_years       DECIMAL(7,4)


  --Check to make sure there is a date for both inputs
  IF @pi_date1 IS NOT NULL and @pi_date2 IS NOT NULL  
  BEGIN

    IF @pi_date1 > @pi_date2 --Make sure the "older" date is in @pi_date1
      BEGIN
        SET @l_tmp_date = @pi_date2
        SET @pi_date2 = @Pi_date1
        SET @pi_date1 = @l_tmp_date
      END

    --Check #1 If date1 + 1 year is greater than date2, difference must be less than 1 year
    IF DATEADD(YYYY,1,@pi_date1) > @pi_date2  
      BEGIN
          --How many days between the two dates (numerator)
        SET @l_days1 = DATEDIFF(dd,@pi_date1, @pi_date2) 
          --subtract 1 year from date2 and calculate days bewteen it and date2
          --This is to get the denominator and accounts for leap year (365 or 366 days)
        SET @l_days2 = DATEDIFF(dd,dateadd(yyyy,-1,@pi_date2),@pi_date2) 
        SET @l_years = @l_days1 / @l_days2 -- Do the math
      END
    ELSE
      --Check #2  Are the dates an exact number of years apart.
      --Calculate years bewteen date1 and date2, then add the years to date1, compare dates to see if exactly the same.
      IF DATEADD(YYYY,DATEDIFF(YYYY,@pi_date1,@pi_date2),@pi_date1) = @pi_date2  
        SET @l_years = DATEDIFF(YYYY,@pi_date1, @pi_date2) --AS Years, 'Exactly even Years' AS Msg
      ELSE
      BEGIN
        --Check #3 The rest of the cases.
        --Check if datediff, returning years, over or under states the years difference
        SET @l_years = DATEDIFF(YYYY,@pi_date1, @pi_date2)
        IF DATEADD(YYYY,@l_years,@pi_date1) > @pi_date2
          SET @l_years = @l_years -1
          --use basicly same logic as in check #1  
        SET @l_days1 = DATEDIFF(dd,DATEADD(YYYY,@l_years,@pi_date1), @pi_date2) 
        SET @l_days2 = DATEDIFF(dd,dateadd(yyyy,-1,@pi_date2),@pi_date2) 
        SET @l_years = @l_years + @l_days1 / @l_days2
        --SELECT @l_years AS Years, 'Years Plus' AS Msg
      END
  END
  ELSE
    SET @l_years = 0  --If either date was null

RETURN @l_Years  --Return the result as decimal(7,4)
END
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Quite Old question, but I want to share what I have done to calculate age

```
    Declare @BirthDate As DateTime
Set @BirthDate = '1994-11-02'

SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,@BirthDate,GETDATE()) - (CASE 
WHEN MONTH(@BirthDate)> MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN 1 
WHEN MONTH(@BirthDate)= MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@BirthDate) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 
Else 0 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to calculate the total days/months/years of an age? do you have a starting date? Or are you trying to dissect it (ex: 24 years, 1 month, 29 days)?

If you have a start date that you're working with, datediff will output the total days/months/years with the following commands:

```
Select DateDiff(d,'1984-07-12','2008-09-11')

Select DateDiff(m,'1984-07-12','2008-09-11')

Select DateDiff(yyyy,'1984-07-12','2008-09-11')
```

with the respective outputs being (8827/290/24).

Now, if you wanted to do the dissection method, you'd have to subtract the number of years in days (days - 365*years), and then do further math on that to get the months, etc.

Comment: When i call 

SELECT DateDiff(yyyy,'1984-07-12','2008-09-11') AS 'age' FROM tbl_product;

get error : Uncaught Error: no such column: yyyy

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` values in T-SQL are stored as floats. You can just subtract the dates from each other and you now have a new date that is the timespan between them.

```
declare @birthdate datetime
set @birthdate = '6/15/1974'

--age in years - short version
print year(getdate() - @birthdate) - year(0)

--age in years - visualization
declare @mindate datetime
declare @span datetime

set @mindate = 0
set @span = getdate() - @birthdate

print @mindate
print @birthdate
print getdate()
print @span
--substract minyear from spanyear to get age in years
print year(@span) - year(@mindate)
print month(@span)
print day(@span)
```

Comment: I guess you'd also need to subtract 1 both from the month and from the day. (In fact, you would be subtracting `month(@span)` and `day(@span)`, respectively, which would be consistent with subtracting `year(@span)`). This answer is the same as Leonardo's, which was also re-posted by simon831 in the form of a function. It's unreliable, anyway. Accuracy/error seems to depend on the number of days in the current month as well as on that in the month of `@birthdate`. Today is `4/5/2012`, I tried your suggestion for `set @birthdate = '4/5/1974'` and got `38 0 1`, even though it should be `38 0 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is SQL code that gives you the number of years, months, and days since the sysdate. 
Enter value for input_birth_date this format(dd_mon_yy). note: input same value(birth date) for years, months & days such as 01-mar-85

```
select trunc((sysdate -to_date('&input_birth_date_dd_mon_yy'))/365) years,
trunc(mod(( sysdate -to_date('&input_birth_date_dd_mon_yy'))/365,1)*12) months,
trunc((mod((mod((sysdate -to_date('&input_birth_date_dd_mon_yy'))/365,1)*12),1)*30)+1) days 
 from dual
```

Comment: This is in Oracle PL/SQL syntax, not T-SQL. It also assumes that years are always 365 days and months are always 30 days

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION DBO.GET_AGE
(
@DATE AS DATETIME
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @YEAR  AS VARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @MONTH AS VARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @DAYS  AS VARCHAR(50) = ''
DECLARE @RESULT AS VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @YEAR  = CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,CASE WHEN DAY(@DATE) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN DATEADD(MONTH,1,@DATE) ELSE @DATE END,GETDATE()) / 12 ))
SET @MONTH = CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,CASE WHEN DAY(@DATE) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN DATEADD(MONTH,1,@DATE) ELSE @DATE END,GETDATE()) % 12 ))
SET @DAYS = DATEDIFF(DD,DATEADD(MM,CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(INT,@YEAR)*12 + CONVERT(INT,@MONTH)),@DATE),GETDATE())

SET @RESULT = (RIGHT('00' + @YEAR, 2) + ' YEARS ' + RIGHT('00' + @MONTH, 2) + ' MONTHS ' + RIGHT('00' + @DAYS, 2) + ' DAYS')

RETURN @RESULT
END

SELECT DBO.GET_AGE('04/12/1986')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @BirthDate datetime, @AgeInMonths int
SET @BirthDate = '10/5/1971'
SET @AgeInMonths                              -- Determine the age in "months old":
    = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @BirthDate, GETDATE())  -- .Get the difference in months
    - CASE WHEN DATEPART(DAY,GETDATE())       -- .If today was the 1st to 4th,
              < DATEPART(DAY,@BirthDate)      --   (or before the birth day of month)
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END                  --   ... don't count the month.
SELECT @AgeInMonths / 12 as AgeYrs            -- Divide by 12 months to get the age in years
      ,@AgeInMonths % 12 as AgeXtraMonths     -- Get the remainder of dividing by 12 months = extra months
      ,DATEDIFF(DAY                           -- For the extra days, find the difference between, 
               ,DATEADD(MONTH, @AgeInMonths   -- 1. Last Monthly Birthday 
                             , @BirthDate)    --     (if birthdays were celebrated monthly)
               ,GETDATE()) as AgeXtraDays     -- 2. Today's date.
```

Comment: To include a code block in your answer, indent it by 4 spaces so that it becomes properly formatted. I edited your post to comply with this.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones that want to create a calculated column in a table to store the age:

```
CASE WHEN DateOfBirth< DATEADD(YEAR, (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, DateOfBirth))*-1, GETDATE()) 
     THEN DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, DateOfBirth)
     ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(YEAR, DateOfBirth) -1 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I calculate the age given a birth date and the current date.

```
select case 
            when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
            else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
        end as MemberAge
go
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way, based on the hours between the two days BUT with the end date truncated.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(hour,Birthdate,CAST(GETDATE() as Date))/8766.0 as INT) AS Age FROM <YourTable>
```

This one has proven to be extremely accurate and reliable. If it weren't for the inner CAST on the GETDATE() it might flip the birthday a few hours before midnight but, with the CAST, it is dead on with the age changing over at **exactly** midnight.

Comment: Close, but I wouln't call it "extremely accurate". It treats every year as 365.25 days, which may yield off-by-one results. Example: '2021-01-01' to '2022-01-01' yields age = 0.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method for calculate age is

See below table

```
    FirstName       LastName    DOB
    sai             krishnan    1991-11-04
    Harish          S A         1998-10-11
```

For finding age,you can calculate through month

```
  Select datediff(MONTH,DOB,getdate())/12 as dates from [Organization].[Employee]
```

Result will be

```
firstname   dates
sai         27
Harish      20
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function `calculateAge` that takes parameter `dateOfBirth` from outside and then it calculates the age in years, months and days and finally it returns in string format.

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateAge(dateOfBirth datetime) RETURNS varchar(40)
BEGIN
    set @currentdatetime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    set @years = TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,dateOfBirth,@currentdatetime);
    set @months = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,dateOfBirth,@currentdatetime) - @years*12 ;
    set @dayOfBirth = EXTRACT(DAY FROM dateOfBirth);
    set @today = EXTRACT(DAY FROM @currentdatetime);
    set @days = 0;
    if (@today > @dayOfBirth) then
        set @days = @today - @dayOfBirth;
    else
        set @decreaseMonth = DATE_SUB(@currentdatetime, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
        set @days = DATEDIFF(dateOfBirth, @decreaseMonth);
    end if;
    RETURN concat(concat( concat(@years , "years\n") , concat(@months , "months\n")), concat(@days , "days"));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of solutions have been given already, but I beleive this one to be both easy to understand and reliable, as it will handle leap years as well :

```
case when datepart(dayofyear, @birth) <= datepart(dayofyear, getdate())
then datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year, @birth)
else datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year, @birth) - 1
end
```

The idea is to simply compute the difference in years between the two years (birth and now), and substract 1 if the anniversary has not been reached for the current year.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to calculate the age given a birth date and the current date.

Query:

```
DECLARE @Date_Of_Birth date = '19991220' -- set Birthday
Select Concat( 
  DATEDIFF(DAY, @Date_Of_Birth , GETDATE()) % 365 % 30, ' Days ' , 
  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Date_Of_Birth, GETDATE()) % 12 , ' Months ', 
  DATEDIFF(MONTH, @Date_Of_Birth, GETDATE())/12, ' Years'
) As Age
```

Output:
Age
27 Days 5 Months 23 Years

Comment: Does this work properly for leap years?  The hard-coded 365 days/year and 30 days/month are sketchy.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @DoB AS DATE = '1968-10-24'
DECLARE @cDate AS DATE = CAST('2000-10-23' AS DATE)

SELECT 
--Get Year difference
DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DoB,@cDate) -
--Cases where year difference will be augmented
CASE 
    --If Date of Birth greater than date passed return 0
    WHEN YEAR(@DoB) - YEAR(@cDate) >= 0 THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DoB,@cDate)

    --If date of birth month less than date passed subtract one year
    WHEN MONTH(@DoB) - MONTH(@cDate) > 0 THEN 1 

    --If date of birth day less than date passed subtract one year
    WHEN MONTH(@DoB) - MONTH(@cDate) = 0 AND DAY(@DoB) - DAY(@cDate) > 0 THEN 1 

    --All cases passed subtract zero
    ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '2016-01-31'
declare @EndDate datetime = '2016-02-01'
SELECT @StartDate AS [StartDate]
      ,@EndDate AS [EndDate]
      ,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Years]
      ,DATEDIFF(Month,(DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate)),@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate),@EndDate) , @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Months]
      ,DATEDIFF(Day, DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month, (DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate)),@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate),@EndDate) , @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate)) ,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Day,DATEDIFF(Day, DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month, (DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate)),@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate),@EndDate) , @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate)) ,@EndDate),DATEADD(Month,DATEDIFF(Month, (DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate)),@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate),@EndDate) , @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ,DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate) - CASE WHEN DATEADD(Year,DATEDIFF(Year,@StartDate,@EndDate), @StartDate) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,@StartDate))) > @EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Days]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select DOB as Birthdate,
       YEAR(GETDATE()) as ThisYear, 
       YEAR(getdate()) - EAR(date1) as Age   
from TableName
```

Comment: @Gvidas `EAR(date1)`? Is that a built-in funciton _[sic]_?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DOB AS Birthdate ,
       YEAR(GETDATE()) AS ThisYear,
       YEAR(getdate()) - YEAR(DOB) AS Age
FROM tableprincejain
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @BirthDate datetime
declare @TotalYear int
declare @TotalMonths int
declare @TotalDays int
declare @TotalWeeks int
declare @TotalHours int
declare @TotalMinute int
declare @TotalSecond int
declare @CurrentDtTime datetime
set @BirthDate='1998/01/05 05:04:00'  -- Set Your date here
set @TotalYear= FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @BirthDate, GETDATE()) / 365.25)
set @TotalMonths= FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEADD(year, @TotalYear,@BirthDate),GetDate()) / 30.436875E)
set @TotalDays= FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(month, @TotalMonths,DATEADD(year, 
    @TotalYear,@BirthDate)), GETDATE()))
set @CurrentDtTime=CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(year, 
    GetDate()))+'/' +CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEPART(MONTH, GetDate()))
    +'/'+ CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEPART(DAY, GetDate()))+' '
    + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEPART(HOUR, @BirthDate))+':'+ 
     CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEPART(MINUTE, @BirthDate))+
   ':'+ CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEPART(Second, @BirthDate)))
set @TotalHours = DATEDIFF(hour, @CurrentDtTime, GETDATE())
if(@TotalHours < 0)
begin
   set @TotalHours = DATEDIFF(hour,DATEADD(Day,-1, @CurrentDtTime), GETDATE())
   set @TotalDays= @TotalDays -1  
 end
set @TotalMinute= DATEPART(MINUTE, GETDATE())-DATEPART(MINUTE, @BirthDate)
 if(@TotalMinute < 0)
set @TotalMinute = DATEPART(MINUTE, DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE()))+(60-DATEPART(MINUTE, 
   @BirthDate))

set @TotalSecond= DATEPART(Second, GETDATE())-DATEPART(Second, @BirthDate)

 Print 'Your age are'+ CHAR(13)
 + CONVERT(varchar(50), @TotalYear)+' Years, ' +
   CONVERT(varchar(50),@TotalMonths) +' Months, ' +
   CONVERT(varchar(50),@TotalDays)+' Days, ' +
   CONVERT(varchar(50),@TotalHours)+' Hours, ' +
   CONVERT(varchar(50),@TotalMinute)+' Minutes, ' + 
   CONVERT(varchar(50),@TotalSecond)+' Seconds. ' +char(13)+
     'Your are born at day of week was - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATENAME(dw , 
     @BirthDate ))
  +char(13)+char(13)+
+'Your Birthdate to till date your '+ CHAR(13)
+'Years - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50), FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @BirthDate, GETDATE()) / 
   365.25))
+' , Months - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEDIFF(MM,@BirthDate,getdate())) 
+' , Weeks - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEDIFF(wk,@BirthDate,getdate()))
+' , Days - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEDIFF(dd,@BirthDate,getdate()))+char(13)+
+'Hours - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEDIFF(HH,@BirthDate,getdate()))
+' , Minutes - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEDIFF(mi,@BirthDate,getdate()))
+' , Seconds - ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),DATEDIFF(ss,@BirthDate,getdate()))
```

Output

```
Your age are
22 Years, 0 Months, 2 Days, 11 Hours, 30 Minutes, 16 Seconds. 
Your are born at day of week was - Monday

Your Birthdate to till date your 
Years - 22 , Months - 264 , Weeks - 1148 , Days - 8037
Hours - 192899 , Minutes - 11573970 , Seconds - 694438216
```

Comment: Too much code....