# Calculating age based on date of birth in SQL and C#?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, c#-2.0

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)
>   [How do I calculate someone’s age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

How to calculate the customer age automatically by using their Date of Birth
using c# and SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate/1572411#1572411):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this on Google: `SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @BirthDate, @TargetDate) / 365.25)`

Where @TargetDate is the date of today (`GETDATE()` in TSQL).

Good luck :)

Comment: This simple but not precise.  For example a person born on 29 -May-1992 would be 17 on 29-May-2009, but this formula returns 16.
See my URL http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/399a7e87-bc78-47a5-8cc2-2d2436886fd7/

Answer (score 0):

Use a SQL function. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/399a7e87-bc78-47a5-8cc2-2d2436886fd7/