# SQL WHERE clause: where age between x and x?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)

Does anyone know how i can set a where clause to say get only those users aged 26-33, by calculating age from date of birth?

I have previously used this to get all users aged below 25 and now i'm just wondering if i could use it to get those aged 26 - 33 or if theres a better way?

```
AND DOB >= ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -25 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AND DOB BETWEEN ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -33 YEAR) AND ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -26 YEAR)
```

(As a suggestion - not tested)

Comment: i'll try it but i think that would bring up anyone under 33 or 26 not actually do what i want which is only bring up those aged 26 to 33

Comment: yeah, I think it will do it..