# Count the amount of years from a certain date SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to count the amount of years from a the year the person is born to today. I have the components to use but dont know how to use them.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()),
CONVERT(INT,+19)))LEFT(TABLE.COLUMN,2)
```

I want to use the +19 to show it before the birtyear. Example in the database the birthyear is showed as YY not YYYY. That is why I want to add the 19, so the SQL will count years from 19YY to 2013.

Comment: Looks like possible duplicate. Please have a look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are asking. Do you want to display the year of birth, which is stored YY in a string, as YYYY? Or do you want to calculate years from year of birth till today?

Comment: Yes! Exactly @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Since Day/Month is missing and birthdates after 31.12.1999 won't work, as comment `Select  DatePart(YY,GETDATE()) - Cast('19' + LEFT(Col,2) as int) as PossibleAge
`

Comment: @andrejcurcic - Answering an "either/or" question with "Yes" doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: @Scorpion that answer will not give an exact answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT  id
    ,   Name
    ,   DATEDIFF(yy, CONVERT(DATETIME, DOB), GETDATE()) AS AGE
    ,   DOB
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: this will not find the age, according to this, when DOB is 2012-12-31 and getdate is 2013-01-01 that child will be 1 year old

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @DOB date = '19680411'
select datediff(year, @DOB, getdate())- case when month(@DOB)*32 + day(@DOB) > 
month(getdate()) * 32 + day(getdate()) then 1 else 0 end
```