# SQL Find Age using DateDiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

---

```
Fields        || Data

ID            || V465

DOB           || 1946-09-05

DATE_OF_DEATH || 1974-05-11
```

---

I am using this SQL but I am getting an error.

```
select DATEDIFF("YYYY",'DOB','DATE_OF_DEATH') where ID= 'V465'
```

Its SQL SERVER Management Studio R2 and

Error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'ID'

Comment: What's the error? And what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: In SQL Server the single quote is a text delimiter - maybe you meant to use [DOB], [DATE_OF_DEATH].

Comment: Seriously? Do you expect SQL Server to guess which table you want to query from?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the `FROM` (and surrounded your column names with single quotes which treats them as string literals):

```
select DATEDIFF("YYYY",DOB,DATE_OF_DEATH) 
FROM {tablename}
where ID= 'V465'
```

And `DATEDIFF` alone is not the right way to determine "age" since

`DATEDIFF("yyyy",'2001-12-01','2003-01-31')`

will give you `2` instead of `1`.

See one method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate) and another [here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2009/12/08/age-calculation-with-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: I also wouldn't use `"YYYY"`... but rather `YEAR` (more explicit, since for example `Y` doesn't do what you think), and I see no need for the double quotes at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YY,'01-01-2001','12-31-2002')
```

Returns 1 on MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

that error most likely comes from not including a table in your select statement

```
select DATEDIFF(YY,DOB,DATE_OF_DEATH) AS AGE
  FROM TABLE_NAME 
 where ID= 'V465'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID  VARCHAR(20),DOB DATE, DATE_OF_DEATH DATE)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('V465', '1946-09-05', '1974-05-11'),('V466', '1945-09-05', '2000-11-11'),
('V467', '1982-09-05', NULL),('V468', '1946-09-05', NULL)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB, COALESCE(DATE_OF_DEATH, GETDATE())) AS AGE
FROM @TABLE
```

Using `COALESCE` function if someone hasnt died yet you can calculate their age too. `COALESCE` function will take difference from date of death and if the column is null it will take difference from today's date. and will give you the following result.

**Result**

```
╔═════╗
║ AGE ║
╠═════╣
║  28 ║
║  55 ║
║  32 ║
║  68 ║
╚═════╝
```