# Multiple Converts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I have looked online and through my book, with no luck on finding the command.  It is the final part of the problem.  "Display the current ages of all the employees." My table and columns are.

```
Table: Employee
Columns: Names(VARCHAR(20),null), 
         Address(VARCHAR(20),null), 
         Employee_Number(INT,null), 
         Salary(SMALLMONEY,null), 
         Birthdate(DATE,null), 
         Employment_Date(DATE,null).
```

Everything I have found online is to convert one or two birth dates into age.  Is there a command to convert multiple ones with out typing in the birth date into the query?

```
DECLARE @dob datetime
SET @dob= '1992-01-09 00:00:00"
```

Would I have to do

```
SELECT NAMES
DECLARE @dob date
SET @dob= 'yyyy-mm-dd'
```

Something like this, I think there is 37 lines of names that I would need to convert there birth date into age.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate

Comment: check http://www.katieandemil.com/sql-age-function-calculate-accurate-age-using-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You already have have the `birthdate` column stored as `date`. To calculate the age, you just need the difference between it and now (which can be returned by the built in function `getdate()`:

```
SELECT name, DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), birthdate) AS age
FROM   employee
```