# To calculate age from DOB and inner join of two tables and then draw Graph

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables TABLE1 and TABLE2 and through inner join of these two tables I will get the DOB( **DD/MM/YYYY** format). Now I have to calculate the age using this DOB and then draw a graph based based on this age(using java). I have no idea how to do it.

**NOTE:** I tried to look for this but I couldn't find a suitable solution for it.
**UPDATE:** I know that I can use PrimeFaces easily to draw graph but I for that I need age.I am having problem in getting age.

**UPDATE** Code to get DOB

```
Select TABLE1.dob 
from TABLE1 INNER JOIN TBALE2 on TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id
```

Comment: what you've done so far? post it here

Comment: @RafaEl Like I said, I have no idea how to do it.I am really new to SQL and hence have no idea abt it. I can get the DOB from inner join but then how to convert it into age is what I dont know

Comment: _"I can get the DOB from inner join.."_ I see you got something there. How you do it? maybe we can modify from it

Comment: @RafaEl I have updated above with the SQL statement for getting DOB

Comment: you may check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)

Comment: @Rafa El even if the answer there is upvoted 54 times, it's a bad one. The answer isn't correct. Leap days will break such attempts. It's easy to avoid such traps see my answer below.

Comment: @VMai well you may check the other answers too

Comment: @Rafa El: the third best rated answer seems to me the first good one. Most answers there are giving bad advice. They would fail on simple tests with leap days.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the current age from date of birth is a question wether the person celebrated his birthday this year or not, pseudocode:

```
if person already celebrated the birthday
    age = current year - year of birth
else
    age = current year - year of birth - 1
```

Using date and time functions of mysql this is not too difficult, see first comment of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#comments

*Number of years between date1 and date2:*

```
IF((YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) > 0, (YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) - (MID(date2, 6, 5) < MID(date1, 6, 5)), IF((YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) < 0, (YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1)) + (MID(date1, 6, 5) < MID(date2, 6, 5)), (YEAR(date2) - YEAR(date1))))
```

You could simplify this, because you know which date is the newer one.