# Declaring a variable with a value from select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, adventureworks

```
DECLARE @age DATETIME
SET @age = (GETDATE() - emp.Birthdate)

SELECT 
    emp.BusinessEntityID, emp.BirthDate, @age
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee AS emp
WHERE 
    emp.OrganizationLevel > = 3 
    AND ((GETDATE() - emp.Birthdate) BETWEEN '1930-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '1940-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

As you pros can see, this will not work, I'm hoping to display the ages of the people who are aged 30-40 with their id, bday and age. declaring the @age is my problem. I tried using `substring(getdate...), 2, 2)` but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What do you need the variable for? You can just add a computed column with the formula `getdate() - emp.birthdate` in your select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use variable in the query. You can do this simply as follow:

```
SELECT t.BusinessEntityID, t.BirthDate, t.Age
FROM
(SELECT emp.BusinessEntityID, emp.BirthDate, CAST(datediff(DAY, emp.Birthdate, GETDATE()) / (365.23076923074) as int) as 'Age'
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS emp
WHERE emp.OrganizationLevel > = 3) t
WHERE t.Age >= 30 and t.Age <=40
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you set the value to `@age`,

```
SET @age = (GETDATE() - emp.Birthdate)
```

there is no `emp`.

You can simply do the following query:

```
SELECT emp.BusinessEntityID, emp.BirthDate, (GETDATE() - emp.Birthdate) AS Age
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS emp
WHERE emp.OrganizationLevel > = 3 AND
      (GETDATE() - emp.Birthdate) BETWEEN '1930-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '1940-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Datediff` function to find exact difference between 2 dates

```
SELECT 
     datediff(yyyy,GETDATE(),date)
FROM 
     [PRGX_AS_SandBox].[dbo].[Test_SO]
```

Comment: It's my first time to use DATEDIFF(), and it looks like i'll be using this more often, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't set a scalar variable with more then one value.
Second, for this purpose you don't need a variable at all.
you can simply do this:

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID, BirthDate, DATEDIFF(Year, BirthDate, GETDATE()) As Age
FROM HumanResources.Employee 
WHERE OrganizationLevel > = 3 
AND DATEDIFF(Year, BirthDate, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 40
```

Note: This will not give an exact age. To get the exact age you can use the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate). I think the best answer there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572938/3094533) by [dotjoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40822/dotjoe)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're Trying to get Employees between 30 and 40 years old you can simply use `DateDiff` Function to do this as the following Query:

```
SELECT BusinessEntityID,BirthDate,DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETDATE()) AS Age 
FROM HumanResources.Employee 
WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR,BirthDate,GETDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 40 
ORDER BY Age ASC
```