# Age not Returned When Executing Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

What could be the problem here when I run the following code as it does not return the age?

```
<% ' calculate age of employee
    bsql  = "select DATEDIFF(yyyy,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())  from employees "
    set brs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    brs.open bsql, dbconn, 1,2%>
<%=rs("DateOfBirth") %>
```

Comment: If this is like most SQL languages then you are not selecting the column, but are creating a new one named `DATEDIFF(yyyy,DateOfBirth,GETDATE())`. Try adding an alias like `select DATEDIFF(yyyy,DateOfBirth,GETDATE()) AS DateOfBirth from employees `

Comment: `DATEDIFF` doesn't answer the question you think it does. It counts the number of *transitions* of the specific date part. `DATEDIFF(year,'20141231','20150101')` returns 1, even though there's only a single day's difference.

Answer (score -1):

As [@ar34z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1479962/ar34z) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174145/age-from-date-of-birth/34175252#comment56095174_34174145) in the comments;

> *"you are not selecting the column, but are creating a new one"*

Once you add any computation to a field in a table you are creating what is known as a *"Computed Column"* or *"Expression"*, specifying `DateOfBirth` as a named field isn't going to work because ADO doesn't know about the column `DateOfBirth` just a unnamed computed column.

Ideally you want to use alias to make computed columns easier to recognise

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(yyyy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) [DateOfBirth]
FROM employees
```

or

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(yyyy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) AS [DateOfBirth]
FROM employees
```

both work fine using SQL Server and have never encountered any issues using either variation.

As the computed column is returning the age *(not the Date Of Birth)* you could just alias the column `[Age]` then use `<%= rs("Age") %>` to output it from the `ADODB.Recordset`.

**Side-Note:** As [@damien-the-unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34174145/age-not-returned-when-executing-query#comment56098884_34174145) in the comments your Age computation isn't very accurate interestingly on this point there is a whole other question already on StackOverFlow with some interesting answers *(just don't take the accepted answer as gospel)*.

- [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1572110/692942)

As it stands *(and this is only my personal opinion)* this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572938/692942) is the best of the bunch.

---

Just for completeness you can also instruct the `ADODB.Recordset` to return fields by ordinal position rather then name by passing a 0 based index of the field position in this case

```
<%= rs(0) %>
```

would work and return the first field in the `SELECT`.

---

Taking all this into account my suggested solution *(for the immediate problem)* would be;

```vb
<% 
' calculate age of employee
bsql  = "SELECT DATEDIFF(yyyy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) [Age] FROM employees"
Set brs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
brs.open bsql, dbconn, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic

Response.Write rs("Age")
%>
```

You will notice that I've replaced numeric values in `brs.Open()` ADODB DLL Constants to see how to use these I recommend reading [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml).

Comment: Wow -1 really, care to elaborate?