# Get between ages from date of birth in sql

Tags: sql

I have a scenario in which I have to get those users whose age is between say (10 - 20) in sql, I have a column with date of birth `dob`. By executing the below query I get the age of all users.

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age     
FROM users
```

My question is how should I write my query so that I can get that users whose age is between 10 to 20

Comment: "By executing the below query I get the age of all users." -- No, you don't. It will not be correct all of the time, even if you don't have any counterexample in your current data.

Comment: I agree, but I want a different query here... I dont have the age column, I only have the dob(date of birth) column

Comment: Also, doesn't `GetDate()` return a date object rather than number of days?  How are storing your `dob` column?

Comment: dob is in this format `1970-03-08 00:00:00`

Comment: @FurquanKhan Even so, there's no reason not to calculate the age correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a SQL-Server available to test right now. I'd try something like:

```
select * from users where datediff(year, dob, getdate()) between 10 and 20;
```

Comment: Btw, `DATEDIFF` doesn't do the same calculation like a human being, it's simply YEAR(getdate) -YEAR(dob)`

Answer (score 1):

First add computed field `Age` like you already did. Then make where filtering on the data.

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT FLOOR((CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) AS Age, * 
   from users) as users
WHERE Age >= 10 AND Age < 20
```

There are [number of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate) to calculate age.

Comment: It is throwing error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName 
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, dob, getdate()) between @dob and @currentDate;
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2014-06-05','2014-08-05') AS DiffDate;
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp
OR

http://sqlhints.com/2015/07/10/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-and-days-in-sql-server/

Comment: Doesn't datediff return integer?

Comment: Yes iut does return integer, check this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Answer (score 0):

Below query should return the users :

```
SELECT *  
from users 
where FLOOR ( (CAST (GetDate() AS INTEGER) - CAST(dob AS INTEGER)) / 365.25) 
between 10 and 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating each users age you might simply change your WHERE-condition to:

```
where dob between cast(dateadd(year, 20, getdate()) as date)
              and cast(dateadd(year, 10, getdate()) as date)
```

Now it's a [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expression and might use an index.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question trying to figure out something very similar. I'm really new to SQL and found a discussion about calculating age from date of birth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate).

I've adapted one of the answers there into this: I think it works.

```
SELECT
    (0 + Convert(Char(8),GETDATE(),112) - Convert(Char(8),dob,112)) / 10000 AS Age
FROM
users
WHERE
    (0 + Convert(Char(8),GETDATE(),112) - Convert(Char(8),dob,112)) / 10000 BETWEEN 10 and 20
;
```