# SQL calculations issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following task:

> Show the list of first, last names and ages of the employees whose age
>   is greater than 55. The result should be sorted by last name.

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    LastName, FirstName,  
    (CASE 
        WHEN (CONVERT(INT, GETDATE()) - CONVERT(INT, BirthDate)) > 55 
           THEN CONVERT(INT, GETDATE()) - CONVERT(INT, BirthDate) 
     END) as Age 
FROM 
    Employees  
ORDER BY 
    LastName
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is the `BirthDate` table (datetime):

[image]

Why does the age go so crazy? What's wrong?

Comment: Because you are converting a `DATE` to `INT` and displaying the `INT` version of the date results?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is a just query language, not a DBMS product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM
     (SELECT 
          LastName, FirstName,  
          (CASE 
              WHEN DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, GETDATE()) > 55 
                 THEN DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, GETDATE()) 
                 ELSE 0 
            END) AS Age 
      FROM 
          Employees) AS ABC
WHERE 
    ABC.Age != 0
ORDER BY 
    ABC.LastName
```

Comment: Try to use `DATEDIFF` function instead what you tried to get the age difference

Comment: datediff only counts the number of date boundaries crossed to get from one date to another. It does not calculate difference. `DateDiff(yy, '31Dec2016', '1Jan2017')` and `DateDiff(yy, '1Jan2016', '31Dec2017')` will both return One (1).

Comment: two days old (`31 dec 2016` to `1 Jan 2017`), is hardly age 1.  although `1 jan 2016 to 31 Dec 2017` is, technically, age 1, it is 729 days old, one day shy of age 2.

Comment: OH! I see, the 2nd case make more sense than the 1st one. Thanks for correcting me such a mistake I have not noticed for long time.

Comment: Until corrected, this answer is WRONG. it will give incorrect age for cases where current date in a year is on or after the individuals Birthday. i.e, if Birthday is 1 June, this will give correct answer every year from 1 Jan up until and including 30 may, but will continue to give the same (INCORRECT) answer from 1 June through 31 December.

Answer (score 1):

For age, use expression

```
 DateDiff(year, birthdate, getdate()) +
    case when Month(getdate()) > Month(birthdate) 
           or Day(getdate()) >= Day(birthdate) 
       then 1 else 0 end
```

i.e.,

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName,  
    DateDiff(year, birthdate, getdate()) +
    case when Month(getdate()) > Month(birthdate) 
           or Day(getdate()) >= Day(birthdate) 
       then 1 else 0 end Age 
FROM Employees  
where DateDiff(year, birthdate, getdate()) +
    case when Month(getdate()) > Month(birthdate) 
           or Day(getdate()) >= Day(birthdate) 
       then 1 else 0 end > 55
ORDER BY LastName
```

Comment: Good example for CT my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your result is you are converting Date to `int` and you didn't convert the `Int` back to `Date`

Add the filter in `Where` clause. To calculate age I always use below method

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, '1990-07-20', getdate()) / 365.25)
```

Result : 26

```
SELECT LastName,
       FirstName,
       Floor(Datediff(DAY, BirthDate, Getdate()) / 365.25) AS Age
FROM   Employees
WHERE  Floor(Datediff(DAY, BirthDate, Getdate()) / 365.25) > 55
ORDER  BY LastName
```

Comment: Why introduce this minor inaccuracy of 0.25 when you can just use year as the parameter in the DATEDIFF function?

Comment: @KRichard - using `year` part is not going to get you exact Age

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to *not* use `datediff()`.  It does not work intuitively.  It counts the number of year boundaries between two dates.  Although there is a relationship between New Year's celebrations and age, the two are not equivalent.

Instead:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName
FROM Employees  
WHERE birthdate < DATEADD(year, -55, getdate())
ORDER BY LastName;
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't get the age.  That is a bit tricky.  You could use `datediff()` just to be "close enough".  The exactly logic is a bit of a pain.  I would refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate).

Comment: This answer has a problem and that's (as you pointed out yourself), is that the query is not returning the age, but in my opinion it has better performance  because of the  Where clause (less row level calculations)

Comment: @FeryalBadili . . . Unfortunately, the accepted answer doesn't correctly calculate age.