# Datetime2 Overflow Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote the SQL below to get a person's age based on the Date of Birth (DOB) field on Client table. However, I got an error message: Adding a value to a 'datetime2' column caused an overflow. Can someone help me to fix it?
Thanks,

```
 SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(day,CLIENT.DOB,'2017-01-01'),
 CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATETIME2)))-1 AS AGE 
 FROM CLIENT
```

Comment: That calculation does not make sense.

Comment: For any date after `2017-01-01` you're adding a negative number of days to `0001-01-01`, which overflows `DATETIME2` because `0001-01-01` is the earliest date that will fit into `DATETIME2`.

Comment: Maybe do it like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate), or one of the many other ways. Just be sure to check if their birthday has occurred yet this year.

Comment: Yeah, you could use `GETDATE()` in place of hard-coded `2017-01-01` but would still have to make sure no future dob's snuck into your data.