# Automatic Age Update in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have employees data in my database, if i insert the employee data it will automatically calculate the age that i written in stored procedure, but if the date of birth of an employee may be tomorrow if i retrieve the employee details will it automatically show the updated one

### Code:

```
Declare @age float 
set @age=(select DATEDIFF(YYYY,@DATE_OF_BIRTH,
GETDATE())) update Employee_details set AGE=@AGE where
BADGE_NO=@BADGE_NO
```

Comment: Do not keep the age in the table.  
Keep the date of birth instead.

Comment: ok.if i want to retrieve the employee age, what should i do

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate. You can use the solution there as a computed column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server, if you store the date of birth, you can add the age as a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (id INT, name VARCHAR(25), dob DATE, 
    age AS (CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112))-CONVERT(CHAR(8),dob,112))/10000)
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, dob) VALUES (1, 'Max Smith', '12/31/1983')
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, dob) VALUES (1, 'Scott Smith', '2/8/1982')
INSERT INTO employees (id, name, dob) VALUES (1, 'Carolyn Smith', '11/1/1985')
```

Note the age column declaration - and thanks cars10m for providing this calculation! - which accurately gives you age based on a date-of-birth column and the current date:

```
age AS (CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112))-CONVERT(CHAR(8),dob,112))/10000)
```

select * from employees gives you (as of today, 8/9/2017):

```
id    name          dob         age
1     Max Smith     1983-12-31  33
1     Scott Smith   1982-02-08  35
1     Carolyn Smith 1985-11-01  31
```

Use a computed column!

Comment: This will run into problems with leap years. Here is an old solution that works reliably, even then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572411/2610061 . You should do something like; `select (convert(int,convert(char(8),getdate(),112))-convert(char(8),@dateOfBirth,112))/10000`

Comment: Thanks @cars10m ! Incorporated your calculation into the answer.

Comment: Thanks A lot Programmers, I'm Just a Beginner now learning all functions in sql.