# SQL Table valued function Age

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I am trying to construct a tvf for calculating age. Currently, I am working with this code, which brings up a few questions.

Code:

```
IF ( MONTH (GETDATE()) = (SELECT MONTH (ISNULL (PERS_DateBirth, '1900-01-01')) 
                          FROM T_Person) 
     AND DAY (GETDATE()) >= (SELECT DAY (ISNULL(PERS_DateBirth, '1900-01-01')) 
                             FROM T_Person)
     OR MONTH (GETDATE()) > (SELECT MONTH (ISNULL (PERS_DateBirth, '1900-01-01')) 
                             FROM T_Person)
   )
SELECT YEAR (GETDATE()) - YEAR (ISNULL (PERS_DateBirth, '1900-01-01')) 
FROM T_Person
ELSE SELECT YEAR (GETDATE()) - YEAR (ISNULL (PERS_DateBirth, '1900-01-01')) - 1  
     FROM T_Person
```

Questions:

1. Subquery returned more than 1 value. How is that possible, considering the code above?
2. Can anyone help me in rewriting this, so that it can be a tvf, maybe using CASE WHEN.

**PS.** I prefer the construct / logic as above, over DATEDIFF constructions using 365,25 days and so on.

Thanks all for helping out, if the code above is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: `SELECT YEAR (GETDATE()) ... FROM T_Person` ... why can't this subquery return more than one row?  There is no `WHERE` clause or restrictions of any other kind preventing it.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh working with SQL2008.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you point out that you see what is wrong. Would be extra helpful if you would suggest code that does work.

Comment: I don't know your data, so I can't suggest anything.  Checking those subqueries should be your first step.

Comment: @SQL_M  if you post sample data and expected result (in tabular text format) it would be easier to try to help you.

Comment: I must be missing something, but what's the problem with SELECT DATEDIFF(YY, PERS_DateBirth, GETDATE()) FROM T_Person ?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate

Comment: Thanks @SteveFord. The answer provided by DotJoe is brilliant.