# Calculate the age in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing this but the result give me all the names who they are 30 years and less than 30 years.

This is the database:

- Donor ( Donor-ID, First-name, Last-name, Date-of-birth, Sex, Date-of-donate)
- Donor-phone (Donor-ID, Phone-number)
- Clinic (Clinic-ID, Clinic-name, Clinic-Location)
- Blood (Blood-ID, Blood Type)
- The donate day (Blood Status, Donate Date)
- Employee (Employee-ID, First-name, Last-name, Sex)

I used this code - where is it wrong?

```
SELECT
    GETDATE () AS FirstName, 
    FirstName, LastName,
    DATEADD(DD, 30, GETDATE()) AS [DateOfDonate- DateOfBirth],
    DATEADD(DD, 1-1-2000, GETDATE()) AS [DonateOfDate]
FROM
    Donor
```

I need to solve this question: find the names of donors who their age is above 30 years and have donated since 1/1/2000

Comment: Okay, `DATEADD()`'s second parameter is an integer.  So in one place you're adding `30` days to `today`, and in another your adding `-2000` days *(you've included a calculation, not a date, and the result of `1 - 1 - 2000` is `-2000`)* to `today`.  But I have no idea what it is that you *want* to do.  The best advice is to give some example data *(from the `donor` table)* and then give some examples results that you want from that example data.  Also, perhaps read this?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Find the names of donors who their age is above 30 years and have donated since 1/1/2000. i want to solve this

Comment: This link is about ["How to calculate age in Years"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate/1572411#1572411) answered by KM.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   donor
WHERE
        [date-of-birth]  <= DATEADD(YEAR, -30, GETDATE())  -- Anyone born more than 30 years ago
    AND [date-of-donate] >= '2000-01-01'                   -- Anyone that donated since 1st Jan 2000
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the previous typo . I calculated with actual fields and then replaced with yours resulting into the mess.
Please use below

```
  cast(datediff(Year,Date-Of-Birth,getdate()) as nvarchar(100))
+ ' Years , '
+ cast(datediff(Month,Date-Of-Birth,getdate())%12 as nvarchar(100))
+ ' months and '
+ cast(datediff(day,Date-Of-Birth,getdate()) as nvarchar(100))
+' days '
```

Comment: i need it  as statement in SQL

Comment: i need to solve this question: Find the names of donors who their age is above 30 years and have donated since 1/1/2000

Comment: The `day` part will give a very large number...  And this sin't what the OP is asking for...

Answer (score -1):

```
 select  FirstName+" "+ LastName from Donor
 where  datediff(year,Date-of-birth,getdate()) >30 and Date-of-donate>
 convert(date,'Date-of-donate',103)=convert(date,'Date-of-
 donate',103)='1/1/2000'
```

This will work for you

Comment: What's this meant to mean? `and Date-of-donate>='' convert(date,'Date-of-donate',103)=convert(date,'Date-of-donate',103)='1/1/2000'`