# Select records by age range

Tags: sql-server

I have following table

```
[tblRegistration](
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DateOfRegistration] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

My question is : select  all records from table tblRegistration where age between 18 to 25 years.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought `DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE())` would suffice to get a year difference, but SQL Server computes only a simple int subtraction for both year numbers, so it returns 1 when asked about difference between 2016.12.31 and 2017.01.01.

So, additionally, accounting for months and days must be done:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        Age = DATEDIFF(yy, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) -
            IIF(DATEPART(m, DateOfBirth) < DATEPART(m, GETDATE()), 0,
            IIF(DATEPART(m, DateOfBirth) > DATEPART(m, GETDATE()), 1,
            IIF(DATEPART(d, DateOfBirth) > DATEPART(d, GETDATE()), 1, 0)))
    FROM tblRegistration
) x
WHERE Age BETWEEN 18 AND 25
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblRegistration 
WHERE DATEDIFF(yyyy, DateOfBirth, GetDate()) BETWEEN 18 and 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I figured the question was a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate), but then I realized OP does not want to list ages; he wants to *filter* on age. That scenario demands a different approach.

To filter on current age, subtract years from the current date, and compare the result to date of birth.

```
DECLARE @today date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
DECLARE @from date = DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -26, @today))
DECLARE @upto date = DATEADD(day, 1, DATEADD(year, -18, @today))

SELECT *
FROM tblRegistration
WHERE DateOfBirth >= @from AND DateOfBirth < @upto
```

No need to compensate for days and months. It even works if column `DateOfBirth` happens to be a `datetime` column that includes the *time* of birth (i.e. it ignores the time, as most people would).

And yes, it works for leap years. For example, when running the query on 2018-02-28, it will:

- exclude persons born on 1992-02-28 (are already celebrating their 26th birthday)
- include persons born on 1992-02-29 (debatable; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29#Born_on_February_29)
- include persons born on 2000-02-28 (celebrating their 18th birthday)
- exclude persons born on 2000-02-29 (again, debatable, but at least consistent with 1992-02-29)

If you prefer Taiwanese legislation (i.e. a 'leapling' formally turns 18 on February 28), then please adjust the `DECLARE` statements as follows.

```
DECLARE @today date = CAST(GETDATE() AS date)
DECLARE @from date = DATEADD(year, -26, DATEADD(day, 1, @today))
DECLARE @upto date = DATEADD(year, -18, DATEADD(day, 1, @today))
```

Due to the fact that `DateOfBirth` is not wrapped inside a function call (as is the case with the `DATEDIFF` approach), the query optimizer will be able to benefit fully from an index on column `DateOfBirth`.
This may result in a substantial performance improvement under the following conditions:

- You have an index on `DateOfBirth`, and this index is likely to be used in the query plan (this may not be the case if there are additional WHERE conditions and joins).
- The number of index keys is huge. (For a regular non-filtered index, this number equals the number of records in the table.)
- The number of rows returned is relatively small compared to the number of index keys.

For example, if your table is holding 100M rows, and you expect to retrieve 1% of these, then the amount of reads done by the `DATEDIFF` approach may actually be a factor 100 higher than in the query above. This is because the query optimizer cannot use an *index seek* in the `DATEDIFF` approach; it will fall back on an *index scan*.