# Is there an SQL query to convert a date to an age

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Suppose I have this query:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE-DOB as age FROM customerDetails 
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(customerid) FROM 
customerDetails)
```

which in SQLTE3 converted a customers date of birth
in the format e.g. 2002-08-11 (as a date field) into their current age, e.g. 17, could I repeat the same logic for an MYSQL query...

Is the syntax different...because the same query produces this when ran in MYSQL Workbench rather than DB Broswswer for SQLite3

```
20198120
```

Comment: You want this solution in mysql ?

Comment: check this answer . `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506731/get-difference-in-years-between-two-dates-in-mysql-as-an-integer`

Comment: This answer deals with the subject thoroughly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756627/calculating-age-from-birthday-tsql-oracle-and-any-others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way to do it is:

```
select YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(20000120)
```

some explanation:

currdate() function returns current date
`Year()` function returns the year for a given date

As GMB commented this solution above will return 18 for your case because the person will have 17 years and 6 months.
This will return years and months:

```
select CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(20020811) -1 
              , '.'
              , ABS(MONTH(CURDATE()) - MONTH(20020811)+1)) as age
FROM customerDetails 
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(customerid) 
                    FROM customerDetails)
```

or if you change it with column name DOB:

```
select CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(DOB) -1 
              , '.'
              , ABS(MONTH(CURDATE()) - MONTH(DOB)+1)) as age
FROM customerDetails 
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(customerid) 
                    FROM customerDetails)
```

`concat()` concatenates parameters inside of the brackets.
Make sure that the column DOB is the column where the date of the birth is inserted...

[Here is a DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0869bf97f8fe87755c9008237f6a91f)

Comment: This does not take into account the date and month, so it behaves like everyone was born on January 1st.

Comment: Thanks @GMB, changed the solution to the one that might be of some help... Cheers!

Comment: I will mark as correct when you show me to include the                      
                                                                                                              
WHERE customerid = SELECT max(customerid)
FROM customerDetails

Comment: @grimReaperZ, I have update my answer. Please do not forget you can now also upvote because you have more than 15 points. Please let me know if something is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Substracting dates in MySQL does not do what you expect. It actually turns the dates to integers, and substracts them. So typically date `2020-01-22` becomes integer `20200122`. This is not what you want.

One method to compute an age is to use [date function `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff), like so:

```
timestampdiff(year, dob, curdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer you can write `DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), '2002/08/11')`.