# How to calculate AVG from two tablets

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a database in SSMS and I am trying to calculate AVG from 2 columns from 2 tablets; I wrote :

```
;WITH combined AS
(
    SELECT Datum_narodenia 
    FROM Zamestnanci 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Datum_narodenia 
    FROM ObčaniaSR
)
SELECT AVG(Datum_narodenia)
FROM combined;
```

But I got this error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1
> Operand data type date is invalid for avg operator.

I created table 1 :

```
CREATE TABLE Zamestnanci
(
    id_Zamestnanca int not null,
    Meno varchar(50) null,
    Priezvisko varchar(50)null,
    Adresa varchar(50) null,
    Datum_narodenia date null,

    PRIMARY KEY (id_Zamestnanca)
);

CREATE TABLE ObčaniaSR
(
    id_Občana int not null,
    Meno varchar(50) null,
    Priezvisko varchar(50) null,
    Adresa varchar(50) null,
    Datum_narodenia date null,
    Zápis_v_trestnom_registry varchar(50) null,

    PRIMARY KEY (id_Občana)
);
```

`Datum_narodenia` means Date_of_birth from witch I try to calculate AVG.

What is best way to calculate AVG age according to you? Thank you for your answers and advice.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your CTE, did you read the error message? Assuming you're using SQL Server given your MSSMS comment, you cannot use `avg()` on `date` columns.

Comment: @Stu So what do you suggest? I am trying to get an age from date and then get avg from it. Is it somehow possible to do it this way? And yes you are right  I am using SQL server

Comment: The first thing you need then is the *age*, not the *date*, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)

Comment: @Stu It gave me `30.033994 30 30 ` Do I have to do this with all the dates in both tablets?

Comment: Aside from the "you can't average a date" issue, the error in the question is because you have a statement _before_ `WITH` that isn't properly terminated with a semi-colon. Please [get in that habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

Comment: FYI SSMS is purely a client interface to SQL Server. So you might be using SSMS to create the database, but its being created in SQL Server.

Comment: @DaleK I am creating the database in MSSMS.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I added `;` there but i got `Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Operand data type date is invalid for avg operator.`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Oh yes I understand now

Comment: @Yes I understand you but I am asking if there is way to do it that way I am making it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty close calculation of age (lots of nitty-gritty [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48779415/61305)) uses the difference in hours between the date and now, divided by the number of hours in a year (8766/24 = 365.25), which tries to roughly account for leap years; it is imperfect, but a pretty good trade-off IMHO between simple and right:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,'19860201',GETDATE())/8766;
```

So:

```
;WITH combined AS
(
    SELECT Datum_narodenia 
    FROM Zamestnanci 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Datum_narodenia 
    FROM ObčaniaSR
)
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(HOUR, Datum_narodenia, GETDATE())/8766)
FROM combined;
```

Now, this does integer math, so you might instead want:

```
;WITH combined AS
(
    SELECT Datum_narodenia 
    FROM Zamestnanci 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Datum_narodenia 
    FROM ObčaniaSR
)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,1), 
  AVG(DATEDIFF(HOUR, Datum_narodenia, GETDATE())/8766.0))
FROM combined;
```

Comment: I got `47.5`  which is right AVG from that values.  So thank you