# Need to join but on a secondary table

Tags: sql

I have this one view all_people_expanded_view that has all the data needed except 1.
The race of client is in race table. But the description is in race_info. I need to join on race on people_id, but really need then to join race on race_info on column race_info_id and then get description. I am stuck on how to make this connection.

```
select a.full_name, a.dob, a.gender, a.ethnicity, c.race_info_id 
from all_people_expanded_view a inner join
     race c
     on a.people_id = c.people_id
```

this would be fine but it only has race_info_id and not the description which is in the race_info_id table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select 
  a.full_name, 
  a.dob, 
  a.gender, 
  a.ethnicity, 
  c.race_info_id,
  ri.description
from 
  all_people_expanded_view a 
inner join
  race c
    on a.people_id = c.people_id
left join --Maybe an inner join, depending on your data
  race_info ri
    on ri.race_info_id = c.race_info_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select
    a.full_name, a.dob, a.gender, a.ethnicity, c.race_info_id , ri.description
from 
    all_people_expanded_view a 
    inner join race c on a.people_id = c.people_id
    inner join race_info ri on ri.race_info_id = c.race_info_id

Comment: I wanted to know if there is a formula or way to get the dob to be as the age ?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate