# TSQL debug age formula

Tags: t-sql

I have an age calculation formula that is returning a negative month value. This does not happen to all values, can someone shed any light as to what the cause is and possibly provide a fix please?

```
Declare @dateofbirth datetime  
Declare @currentdatetime datetime  
Declare @years varchar(40)  
Declare @months varchar(30)  
set @dateofbirth='1982-12-16'--birthdate  
select concat(datediff(year,@dateofbirth,getdate()),'\',   datediff(month,@dateofbirth,getdate())-(datediff(year,@dateofbirth,getdate())*12))  [Year\Month]
```

RESULT : 
Year\Month
37-3

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are implicitly assuming their birthday has already occurred this year.

`Declare @dateofbirth datetime
Declare @currentdatetime datetime
Declare @years varchar(40)
Declare @months varchar(30)
set @dateofbirth='1982-12-16'--birthdate 
select concat(DATEDIFF(MONTH,CASE WHEN DAY(@dateofbirth) > DAY(GETDATE())THEN DATEADD(MONTH,1,@dateofbirth)ELSE @dateofbirth END,GETDATE()) / 12
            ,'\'
            ,DATEDIFF(MONTH,CASE WHEN DAY(@dateofbirth) > DAY(GETDATE())THEN DATEADD(MONTH,1,@dateofbirth)ELSE @dateofbirth END,GETDATE()) % 12
            )[Year\Month]`

Answer (score 1):

The cause is this part:

```
datediff(year,@dateofbirth,getdate())*12
```

datediff doesn't count whole years it counts boundaries crossed so the following returns 1 even though a single day has passed:

```
SELECT datediff(year,'2019-12-31','2020-01-01')
```

There are a lot of suggestions on how to accurately handle age calculations [in this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate) if you need to show age in years and months then it shouldn't be too hard to adapt these to what you need.