# Case when to sort EGN by groups of age

Tags: sql-server, case

How to use case when to sort groups by age 0-18,18-30,30-40 using their EGN. Maybe using something like `>87______`, example of EGN `8607051914` this should be in the group `30-40`.

Comment: What have you tried? Where didn't it work?

Comment: Still trying to figure it out because the thing that came to me is to put it as Case when [EGN]>=7900000000 and [EGN] <=8900000000 then '30-40' but this targets only the year so a person may still not be 30y old in this format. And for the groups 18-30 the EGN for 18 is 01 for the year so i don't know exatcly how to put in a case when when the year for 30 is 89.

Comment: Please, define EGN. Is this unique person id?

Comment: Start with calculating the current age.

Comment: EGN is Unique person id, yes.

Comment: How do i calculate the current age like this?

Comment: Is the EGN `YYMMDDnnnn`, i.e. date of birth etc?

Comment: Yeah its YYMMDDnnnn the 4 n's are randomised and don't need to be exact. Date of birth exactly.

Comment: @RinganarR Is this a bulgarian EGN?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_citizenship_number ? Someone must have written code to calculated current age.

Comment: Yes it's for bulgarian type ID.

Comment: To get the date first maybe we can use something that adds the number to make it a full year so for the year 99 to add 1900 to get the full year and sort it by that, but how can this be done in SQL Server, i found something for oracle :

Comment: Select
EGN,
(CASE WHEN (Month_temp>20)AND(Month_temp<33) THEN Month_temp - 20
      WHEN (Month_temp>40)AND(Month_temp<53) THEN Month_temp - 40
      ELSE Month_temp
  END) as The_Month,

(CASE WHEN (Month_temp>20)AND(Month_temp<33) THEN Year_temp + 1800
      WHEN (Month_temp>40)AND(Month_temp<53) THEN Year_temp + 2000
      ELSE Year_temp + 1900
  END) as The_Year
From 
( 
  Select
    EGN,
    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(EGN,1,2)) as Year_temp, 
    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(EGN,3,2)) as Month_temp
  From TABLE_WITH_EGN_COLUMN
)

Comment: [Edit] any clarifications etc directly into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a specific calculation, because `EGN` seems to be a bulgarian citizen number. The important part for the calculation is that the initial six digits correspond to the birth date, but the month number is encoded:

- for date of birth between `01/01/1900` and `31/12/1999` month remains the same
- for date of birth before `01/01/1900` `20` is added to the month,
- for date of birth betwenn `01/01/2000` and `31/12/2099`, `40` is added to the month:

The following statement is a possible approach:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (egn varchar(10))
INSERT INTO Data (egn) VALUES ('8607051914')
```

Table:

```
SELECT 
    egn,
    CASE 
        WHEN 0 <= age AND age < 18 THEN '0-18'
        WHEN 18 <= age AND age < 30 THEN '18-30'
        WHEN 30 <= age AND age < 40 THEN '30-40'
        ELSE '40+'
    END AS age
FROM (
    SELECT 
        egn,
        DATEDIFF(
            year,
            DATEFROMPARTS(
                CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) BETWEEN '21' AND '32' THEN '18' + SUBSTRING(egn, 1, 2) 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) BETWEEN '41' AND '52' THEN '20' + SUBSTRING(egn, 1, 2) 
                    ELSE '19' + SUBSTRING(egn, 1, 2) END, 
                CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) BETWEEN '21' AND '32' THEN SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) - 20
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) BETWEEN '41' AND '52' THEN SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) - 40
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(egn, 3, 2) END, 
                SUBSTRING(egn, 5, 2)
            ),
            GETDATE()
        ) AS age
    FROM Data
) t
```

Result:

```
egn         age
8607051914  30-40
```

Comment: It is working correctly, but how can it be integrated to use the table instead of a fixed input?

Comment: @RinganarR it's almost the same, see the updated answer.

Comment: Just to note, `DATEDIFF(YEAR` doesn't actually work when determining ages. There's a good post here about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate