# SQL Server : check if user is old enough

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to check if a user is old enough. I tried as shown here, but this only works for years.

So, for example 11/7/2003 should be true but 12/12/2003 should be false. But, with my code each of these is true.

Here is my code:

```
[birthdate]date CHECK(DATEDIFF(year,birthdate,getdate()) >= 18),
```

How can I write this in another way that the months and days will matter?

Comment: Aside comment: `SSMS` is the user interface that many of us use to interact with SQL Server. The database engine, SQL Server, is relevant to coding questions. The interface is not.

Comment: FYI, `DATEDIFF(year,birthdate,getdate())` is not a good way to determine someone's age. People are born on days other than 01 January.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing arithmetic on the column and checking the result, do arithmetic on `GETDATE` and do a normal comparison

```sql
[birthdate]date CHECK(birthdate <= DATEADD(year, -18, getdate())),
```

This is good practice in any case for `WHERE` and `JOIN` predicates, as it means indexes can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Want to find people who are at least 18, given then date of birth?

```sql
SELECT Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date) AS today
     , DateAdd(yy, -18, Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS date)) AS eighteen_years_ago
;
```

Anyone born on or before `eighteen_years_ago` is *at least* 18 years old.

Answer (score -1):

Check the number of days from date A to B and replace the condition with >= 6570  (365*18).

This method does not check for leap years.