# how to update database field every year

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2008, auto-update

I have a database which contains 2 fields called `DateOfBirth` and `Age`, for storing users DOB and age respectively. I want the `Age` column to be automatically incremented by 1 every year, according to the DOB matching server date.

What could be the best way for achieving this? I am using **asp.net** and **sql server 2008**.

Comment: Why are you storing both?  You should be storing DOB and calculating age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than store both the `DateOfBirth` and `Age`, create a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) on the table that calculates the age:

```
[Age] AS datediff(year,  DateOfBirth, getdate())
```

So in yout table creation:

```
-- Create Table with computed column
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCtest]
(
    [id] [int] not NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
    -- etc...
    [Age] AS datediff(year,  DateOfBirth, getdate()) 
)
GO
```

If you want to persist the computed value add the `PERSISTED` keyword.

One possibility, if you want Age displayed in years and months:

```
    [AgeInDays] AS datediff(day,  DateOfBirth, getdate())
```

then create a view over your table that formats `AgeInDays` into years and months.

Here is another possibility, using a computed column of `[AgeYears]`:

```
create view vwCCtestAge
AS
select 
   id, 
   dateofbirth,
   cast([AgeYears] as varchar(4)) + ' years ' + 
      cast(datediff(month, DateOfBirth, getdate()) 
           - case when (AgeYears > 0) then (AgeYears - 1)*12 
                  else 0 
             end as varchar(4)) + ' months' as Age
   from cctest2
   GO
```

[You should check for boundary cases...]

Comment: @Mitch: can you please elaborate, what you mean by computed column, and how it will help me for updating age field every year.. automatically... no manuals...

Comment: is it possible to display whole age including month and days... in sql server

Comment: @Mitch: can you please help me for the same also..
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Abbas: I'm sure it would make a good *new* question to ask *after you've made sure there hasn't been one already*. Take a look, for example, at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-tsql-with-years-months-and-days

Comment: @Andriy M : it's a slightly different question

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: In what way? I'm not quarrelling, just can't see the difference.

Comment: @Mitch: Well, I understand that this one is about updating, but the main question is probably about calculating, isn't it?