# Calculate age of a person in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

It seems like something simple, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I want to calculate the age of someone base on two dates in SQL.

I did DATEDIFF(year,Birthdate,ReferenceDate) and it doesn't always give me the right age.

For example

```
DATEDIFF(year,'1981-07-05',2011-07-01')
```

gives 30, while it should still be 29. Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your datepart is `year`, so it only considers `1981` and `2011`. Have a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx). Also, havev a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days

Comment: There is an article that explains it, it doesn't calculate the year between the dates, it calculates the number of years between the years. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/datediff-function-demystified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
 (DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend) , @datestart) > @dateend)
THEN DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend) -1
ELSE DATEDIFF(year, @datestart  ,@dateend)
END
```

It just compares the year difference and if it is greater then subtracts a year, else it returns the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Date1 datetime
Declare @Date2 datetime


Select @Date1 = '07/25/1984'
Select @Date2 = GetDate()

select CASE
WHEN dateadd(year, datediff (year, @Date1, @Date2), @Date1) > @Date2
THEN datediff (year, @Date1, @Date2) - 1
ELSE datediff (year, @Date1, @Date2)END as Age
```

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, GETDATE()) - CASE
    WHEN MONTH(BirthDate) > MONTH(GETDATE())
    OR (MONTH(BirthDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
    AND DAY(BirthDate) > DAY(GETDATE()))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Age;

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select
    (datediff(yy,'1981-07-08',getdate()))-(datepart(yy,(convert(datetime,convert(int,dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,'1981-07-08',getdate()),'1981-07-08'))-convert(int,dateadd(yy,-1,getdate())))))-1900)
```