# mysql How can i get date difference result in such a formate year:month:day

Tags: mysql

i want to get date difference.

i am using this query:- `SELECT DATEDIFF('2012-08-01', '1978-12-06') AS intval ;`

but this is returning only number of days. but i want result such like this:-

result:- `33year,2month,12days`

please suggest me how can i write such type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a calculator for date difference

Please refer thie link

[How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

this is a stackoverflow link

Comment: Thank you pradeep, but can you provide me sql query for this.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days

Comment: hey, you have provide some wrong information. The calculator does not required mysql to generate the differences. **Most importantly, It does not generate accordingly to the format**