# Calculating and showing Age Column on Sql Server as (xx Years, xx months)

Tags: c#, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

I have a problem with age calculation on Sql Server 2005. I have a customers table which has date of `birth column`. What i want is to create view which has an `age column` and this `age column` should show the age of a `person` by subtracting the date of birth from today(pretty simple).

I found a couple of good resources here but what i want exactly is to show the age by years and months. eg.(47 yrs, 3 months). This means i want to have both the year and month values and i want to add a `string` (either `'years', 'yrs', 'y', 'months', 'mon', 'm', ...`) to the appropriate value and display it as eg. (`25 years, 2 months`). 
And if the person's age is just for example `3 months`, it should display '`3 months`', not `'0 years, 3 months`'.

If the person's age is some years without any months, it should display eg. '`5 years`' not `'5 years, 0 months`'

Oh, I have already done that using c# but i want to create a column on the sql view so that i can just populate my gridview using the view without doing any calculation on my c# code.
If it helps i can post my c# code here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `format_age` function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION format_age(
    @DOB datetime,
    @now datetime
)
RETURNS nvarchar(30)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @years int, @months int;
    IF @DOB > @now RETURN N'not born yet';
    SET @years = DATEDIFF(year, @DOB, @now);
    IF MONTH(@DOB) * 100 + DAY(@DOB) > MONTH(@now) * 100 + DAY(@now)
        SET @years = @years - 1;
    SET @months = DATEDIFF(month, DATEADD(year, @years, @DOB), @now);
    IF DAY(@DOB) > DAY(@now)
        SET @months = @months - 1;
    RETURN CASE
        WHEN @years = 0 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @months) + N' months'
        WHEN @months = 0 THEN CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @years) + N' years'
        ELSE CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @years) + N' years, ' +
            CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @months) + N' months'
    END;
END
GO
```

Here's some test cases:

```sql
SELECT '2011-02-16' AS dt, dbo.format_age('2011-02-16', '2012-03-16') AS age UNION
SELECT '2011-03-16',       dbo.format_age('2011-03-16', '2012-03-16')        UNION
SELECT '2011-03-17',       dbo.format_age('2011-03-17', '2012-03-16')        UNION
SELECT '2012-03-16',       dbo.format_age('2012-03-16', '2012-03-16')        UNION
SELECT '2012-03-17',       dbo.format_age('2012-03-17', '2012-03-16')
```

And here's the result<sup>*</sup>:

```
| dt          | age               |
|-------------|-------------------|
| 2011-02-16  | 1 years, 1 months |
| 2011-03-16  | 1 years           |
| 2011-03-17  | 11 months         |
| 2012-03-16  | 0 months          |
| 2012-03-17  | not born yet      |
```

<sup>*Reference date is 2012-03-16</sup>

Comment: shows this error when executing the query on sql server management studio.

Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Procedure format_age, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure format_age, Line 10
Must declare the scalar variable "@years".
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Procedure format_age, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure format_age, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@months".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure format_age, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@years".

Comment: Assigning a value with the `DECLARE` statement was introduced in SQL Server 2008. I updated the answer to split it up into a separate `DECLARE` and `SET`.

Comment: Tested on SQL Server 2000, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider localization issues with that solution (and different *standards* to calculate the age in different countries). If you do not care about that you may:

- Write a SQL scalar function to calculate the age (see [these posts on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/399a7e87-bc78-47a5-8cc2-2d2436886fd7)).
- Write a C# function and integrate it in SQL Server (see [this article on SQLTeam](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/writing-clr-stored-procedures-in-charp-introduction-to-charp-part-1)).

Comment: Thanks, i just converted my C# code to an Sql function which i used in my view.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT *,
  case when DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthday, GETDATE()) < 12
  then 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(16), DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthday, GETDATE())) + ' months'
  else 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(16), DATEDIFF(YEAR, Birthday, GETDATE())) + ' years, ' + 
    CONVERT(nvarchar(16), DATEDIFF(MONTH, Birthday, GETDATE()) % 12 ) + ' months'
  end 
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER
```

Comment: This was also a good one but it gives wrong answers sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(birthDay DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    ('2004-04-05'),
    ('2001-02-05')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH Years
AS
(   
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(yy, tbl.birthDay, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(tbl.birthDay) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(tbl.birthDay) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(tbl.birthDay) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Years,
        tbl.birthDay
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl 
), BithDayWithMonth
AS
(
    SELECT
        Years.Years,
        DATEDIFF(m, years.tmp, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(Years.birthDay) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Months
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                DATEADD(yy, Years.Years, Years.birthDay) AS tmp,
                Years.Years,
                Years.birthDay
            FROM
                Years
        ) AS years
)
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN BithDayWithMonth.Years=0 THEN '' ELSE CAST(BithDayWithMonth.Years AS VARCHAR(10))+' years' END)+
    (CASE WHEN BithDayWithMonth.Months=0 THEN '' ELSE (CASE WHEN NOT BithDayWithMonth.Years=0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END) +
    CAST(BithDayWithMonth.Years AS VARCHAR(10))+' months' END)
FROM
    BithDayWithMonth
```

Comment: Query executes successfully but there are some irregular values like
24 years, 24 months (using 3/17/2012 as now and 3/20/1987 as Birth Date)