# How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server

this question is an extension of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days/11139005)

i tried to extend Dane's answer, but the result is a little problematic.

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @dateTo DATETIME
DECLARE @tmpdate DATETIME 
DECLARE @years INT
DECLARE @months INT
DECLARE @days INT
DECLARE @hours INT
DECLARE @minutes INT
DECLARE @seconds INT
DECLARE @milliseconds INT

SELECT @dateFrom = '2011-01-01 11:24:38:100'
SELECT @dateTo = '2012-01-01 11:24:38:110'

SELECT @tmpdate = @dateFrom

SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, @dateTo) 
        - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@dateFrom) > MONTH(@dateTo)) OR (MONTH(@dateFrom) =  MONTH(@dateTo) AND DAY(@dateFrom) > DAY(@dateTo))
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate)
SELECT @months          = DATEDIFF(mm, @tmpdate, @dateTo) - CASE WHEN   DAY(@dateFrom) > DAY(@dateTo) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(mm, @months, @tmpdate)
SELECT @days            = DATEDIFF(dd, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(dd, @days, @tmpdate)
SELECT @hours           = DATEDIFF(hh, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(hh, @hours, @tmpdate)
SELECT @minutes         = DATEDIFF(mi, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(mi, @minutes, @tmpdate)
SELECT @seconds         = DATEDIFF(ss, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(ss, @seconds, @tmpdate)
SELECT @milliseconds    = DATEDIFF(ms, @tmpdate, @dateTo)

SELECT
    @years AS [years]
    , @months AS [months]
    , @days AS [days]
    , @hours AS [hours]
    , @minutes AS [minutes]
    , @seconds AS [seconds]
    , @milliseconds AS [milliseconds]
```

and the result is :

```
years   months  days    hours   minutes seconds milliseconds
1       0       0       0       0       0       10
```

but when i run:

```
SELECT @dateFrom = '2011-01-02 11:24:38:110'
SELECT @dateTo = '2012-01-01 10:23:37:100'
```

the result is :

```
years   months  days    hours   minutes seconds milliseconds
0       11      30      -1      -1      -1      -10
```

help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is correct but it showing in negative values.You need to use abs to return positive values

```
 SELECT
 @years AS [years]
, abs(@months) AS [months]
, abs(@days) AS [days]
, abs(@hours) AS [hours]
, abs(@minutes) AS [minutes]
, abs(@seconds) AS [seconds]
, abs(@milliseconds) AS [milliseconds]
```

Comment: The code you provided dose not handle all cases correct. For exmaple, try, dateFrom : '2014-04-24 13:59:00' dateTo: '2014-04-24 14:01:00'

Answer (score 2):

You get these negative values because the date in @dateFrom comes later than the date in @dateTo, i think the best you can do is swapping these values before the process start when this happens, so you won't need to reformat your variables after the process:

```
DECLARE @auxDate DATETIME

IF (@dateFrom>@dateTo) 
BEGIN
     SET @auxDate = @dateFrom
     SET @dateFrom = @dateTo
     SET @dateTo = @auxDate
END

     -- Your code..
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CMN.UFN_AGE 
(   @DATE_BEG DATETIME,
    @DATE_END DATETIME
) RETURNS NVARCHAR(255) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Ret NVARCHAR(255) = NULL;
    DECLARE @s INT = DATEPART(SECOND, @DATE_END);
    DECLARE @n INT = DATEPART(MINUTE, @DATE_END);
    DECLARE @h INT = DATEPART(HOUR, @DATE_END);
    DECLARE @d INT = DATEPART(DAY, @DATE_END);
    DECLARE @m INT = DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_END);
    DECLARE @y INT = DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_END);

    IF (NOT ((@DATE_BEG IS NULL) OR (@DATE_END IS NULL))) 
    BEGIN
        IF (@DATE_BEG < @DATE_END)
        BEGIN
            IF (@s < DATEPART(SECOND, @DATE_BEG))
            BEGIN
                SET @s = @s + 60;
                SET @DATE_END = DATEADD(MINUTE,-1,@DATE_END);
                SET @n = DATEPART(MINUTE, @DATE_END);
                SET @h = DATEPART(HOUR, @DATE_END);
                SET @d = DATEPART(DAY, @DATE_END);
                SET @m = DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_END);
                SET @y = DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_END);
            END
            IF (@n < DATEPART(MINUTE, @DATE_BEG))
            BEGIN
                SET @n = @n + 60;
                SET @DATE_END = DATEADD(HOUR,-1,@DATE_END);
                SET @h = DATEPART(HOUR, @DATE_END);
                SET @d = DATEPART(DAY, @DATE_END);
                SET @m = DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_END);
                SET @y = DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_END);
            END
            IF (@h < DATEPART(HOUR, @DATE_BEG))
            BEGIN
                SET @h = @h + 24;
                SET @DATE_END = DATEADD(DAY,-1,@DATE_END);
                SET @d = DATEPART(DAY, @DATE_END);
                SET @m = DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_END);
                SET @y = DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_END);
            END

            SET @d = @d + DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH(@DATE_BEG)) - DATEPART(DAY, @DATE_BEG);
            IF (@d = DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH(@DATE_BEG)))
            BEGIN
                SET @d = 0
            END
            ELSE IF (@d > DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH(@DATE_BEG)))
            BEGIN
                SET @d = @d - DATEPART(DAY, EOMONTH(@DATE_BEG));
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @DATE_END = DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@DATE_END);
                SET @m = DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_END);
                SET @y = DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_END);
            END

            IF (@m < DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_BEG))
            BEGIN
                SET @m = @m + 12;
                SET @DATE_END = DATEADD(YEAR,-1,@DATE_END);
                SET @y = DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_END);
            END

            SET @s = @s - DATEPART(SECOND, @DATE_BEG);
            SET @n = @n - DATEPART(MINUTE, @DATE_BEG);
            SET @h = @h - DATEPART(HOUR, @DATE_BEG);
            SET @m = @m - DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE_BEG);
            SET @y = @y - DATEPART(YEAR, @DATE_BEG);

            SET @Ret = CONCAT(CASE WHEN (@y < 1) THEN '' ELSE
                CONCAT(FORMAT(@y, '00'), ' year(s)  ') END,
                CASE WHEN (@m < 1) THEN '' ELSE
                CONCAT(FORMAT(@m, '00'), ' month(s)  ') END,
                CASE WHEN (@d < 1) THEN '' ELSE
                CONCAT(FORMAT(@d, '00'), ' day(s)  ') END,
                FORMAT(@h, '00'), ':', FORMAT(@n, '00'), ':', FORMAT(@s, '00'));
        END
    END
    RETURN @Ret;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dateFrom DATETIME
DECLARE @dateTo DATETIME
DECLARE @tmpdate DATETIME 
DECLARE @years INT
DECLARE @months INT
DECLARE @days INT
DECLARE @hours INT
DECLARE @minutes INT
DECLARE @seconds INT
DECLARE @milliseconds INT
DECLARE @sign CHAR

--SELECT @dateFrom = '2011-01-01 11:24:38:100'
--SELECT @dateTo = '2012-01-01 11:24:38:110'

SELECT @dateFrom    = '2012-02-03 11:24:38:000'
SELECT @dateTo      = '2013-03-04 12:25:39:003'
SELECT @sign        = '+'

IF @dateFrom > @dateTo
BEGIN
    SET @tmpdate = @dateFrom
    SET @dateFrom = @dateTo
    SET @dateTo = @tmpdate
    SET @sign = '-'
END

SELECT @tmpdate = @dateFrom

SELECT @years           = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, @dateTo) 
                            - CASE WHEN
                                   (DATEPART(mm, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(mm, @dateTo)) 
                                OR (DATEPART(mm, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(mm, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(dd, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(dd, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(dd, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(dd, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(hh, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(hh, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(hh, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(hh, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(mi, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(mi, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ss, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(ss, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ms, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ms, @dateTo))
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate)
SELECT @months          = DATEDIFF(mm, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
                            - CASE WHEN
                                   (DATEPART(dd, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(dd, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(dd, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(dd, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(hh, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(hh, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(hh, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(hh, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(mi, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(mi, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ss, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(ss, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ms, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ms, @dateTo))
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(mm, @months, @tmpdate)
SELECT @days            = DATEDIFF(dd, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
                            - CASE WHEN
                                   (DATEPART(hh, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(hh, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(hh, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(hh, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(mi, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(mi, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ss, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(ss, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ms, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ms, @dateTo))
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(dd, @days, @tmpdate)
SELECT @hours           = DATEDIFF(hh, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
                            - CASE WHEN
                                   (DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(mi, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(mi, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(mi, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ss, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(ss, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ms, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ms, @dateTo))
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(hh, @hours, @tmpdate)
SELECT @minutes         = DATEDIFF(mi, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
                            - CASE WHEN
                                   (DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ss, @dateTo))
                                OR (DATEPART(ss, @dateFrom) = DATEPART(ss, @dateTo) AND DATEPART(ms, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ms, @dateTo))
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(mi, @minutes, @tmpdate)
SELECT @seconds         = DATEDIFF(ss, @tmpdate, @dateTo)
                            - CASE WHEN
                                   (DATEPART(ms, @dateFrom) > DATEPART(ms, @dateTo))
                                THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                            END
SELECT @tmpdate         = DATEADD(ss, @seconds, @tmpdate)
SELECT @milliseconds    = DATEDIFF(ms, @tmpdate, @dateTo)

SELECT
    @sign AS [sign]
    , @years AS [years]
    , @months AS [months]
    , @days AS [days]
    , @hours AS [hours]
    , @minutes AS [minutes]
    , @seconds AS [seconds]
    , @milliseconds AS [milliseconds]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my question which was answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242773/ms-sql-server-calculate-age-with-accuracy-of-hours-and-minuets).
It deals with a case like :

@dateFrom = '2014-04-24 13:59:00'
@dateTo = '2014-04-24 14:01:00'

Your code returns a wrong date for these values.