# MS SQL Server : calculate age with accuracy of hours and minuets

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, datediff

I need an SQL function to calculate age. It has to be accurate and cover all corner cases.
It is for hospital ward for babies, so age of 30 minuets is a common case.

I have a looked on other answers but could not find one that deals with all cases.

For example:

- Baby born in 2014-04-29 12:59:00.000.
- And now is 2014-04-29 13:10:23.000,

Age should be 0 Years, 0 Months, 0 Days, 0 Hours, **11 minutes**

It would be great if someone can provide the ultimate and definitive version of that function.

(I am afraid that simple **solutions with DateDiff are not good enough**. As stated in a more popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days/11139005)  : "The Datediff function doesn't handle year boundaries well ..."

Comment: It is a MS-SQL database.

Comment: Does all of this have to be done in a query or can some of it be done in the calling application? If so what is the language you're using for that app?

Comment: `Select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',GETDATE())` ??

Comment: Can you edit your question and give some more examples of what you want to see for the age?

Comment: @Bob Brinks all should be done in an SQL function.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff added to the question.

Comment: @Yaron Levi I would no recommend that, there are libraries in most languages to go from a date to a nicely formatted string like "3 weeks, 1 hour, and 45 minutes ago". In SQL you would have to come up with this function yourself (see RezaRahmati's awnser).

Comment: @RezaRahmati The formatting is not an issue for me, it was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `DATEDIFF` to get the Year, Month, and Day differences, and then simple division for the Seconds, Minutes, and Hours differences.

I've used `@CurrentDate` to recreate the original request, but `@CurrentDate = GETDATE()` will return the age at time of execution.

```
DECLARE @BirthDate DATETIME
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
SET @BirthDate = '2014-04-29 12:59:00.000'
SET @CurrentDate = '2014-04-29 13:10:23.000'

DECLARE @DiffInYears INT
DECLARE @DiffInMonths INT
DECLARE @DiffInDays INT
DECLARE @DiffInHours INT
DECLARE @DiffInMinutes INT
DECLARE @DiffInSeconds INT
DECLARE @TotalSeconds BIGINT


-- Determine Year, Month, and Day differences
SET @DiffInYears = DATEDIFF(year, @BirthDate, @CurrentDate)
IF @DiffInYears > 0
    SET @BirthDate = DATEADD(year, @DiffInYears, @BirthDate)
IF @BirthDate > @CurrentDate
BEGIN
    -- Adjust for pushing @BirthDate into future
    SET @DiffInYears = @DiffInYears - 1
    SET @BirthDate = DATEADD(year, -1, @BirthDate)
END

SET @DiffInMonths = DATEDIFF(month, @BirthDate, @CurrentDate)
IF @DiffInMonths > 0
    SET @BirthDate = DATEADD(month, @DiffInMonths, @BirthDate)
IF @BirthDate > @CurrentDate
BEGIN
    -- Adjust for pushing @BirthDate into future
    SET @DiffInMonths = @DiffInMonths - 1
    SET @BirthDate = DATEADD(month, -1, @BirthDate)
END

SET @DiffInDays = DATEDIFF(day, @BirthDate, @CurrentDate)
IF @DiffInDays > 0
    SET @BirthDate = DATEADD(day, @DiffInDays, @BirthDate)
IF @BirthDate > @CurrentDate
BEGIN
    -- Adjust for pushing @BirthDate into future
    SET @DiffInDays = @DiffInDays - 1
    SET @BirthDate = DATEADD(day, -1, @BirthDate)
END

-- Get number of seconds difference for Hour, Minute, Second differences
SET @TotalSeconds = DATEDIFF(second, @BirthDate, @CurrentDate)

-- Determine Seconds, Minutes, Hours differences
SET @DiffInSeconds = @TotalSeconds % 60
SET @TotalSeconds = @TotalSeconds / 60

SET @DiffInMinutes = @TotalSeconds % 60
SET @TotalSeconds = @TotalSeconds / 60

SET @DiffInHours = @TotalSeconds


-- Display results
 SELECT @DiffInYears AS YearsDiff,
        @DiffInMonths AS MonthsDiff,
        @DiffInDays AS DaysDiff,
        @DiffInHours AS HoursDiff,
        @DiffInMinutes AS MinutesDiff,
        @DiffInSeconds AS SecondsDiff
```

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you date diff in minutes,

```
select datediff(mi, '2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',getdate())
```

Then you can simply calc the `minutes/60` for `hours` and `minutes mod 60` for `minutes`

```
select datediff(mi, '2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',getdate())/60 as [Hours], select datediff(mi, '2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',getdate()) % 60 as [Minutes]
```

Comment: @eggyal DateDiff in MySql accepts 2 parameters but in SQL Server accepts 3 parameters, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It will give you [date diff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) in seconds `select datediff(s, '2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',getdate())`

Comment: and you can go on.. `select datediff(s, '2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',getdate())/60` will give you minutes

Comment: also `select datediff(mi, '2014-04-23 05:23:59.660',getdate())` will give you minutes

Comment: @VijaySinghRana `m` will give `months`, `n` or `mi` is for `minutes`