# How to return a string difference between two dates (current date and input date) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a function, which is written in JavaScript for getting the date time in **day/month/year hours/minutes/seconds AM/PM** format. What I want is a function, which will allow me to return the string of the following type (1 second, or 5 seconds, or 2 minutes, or 4 hours, or 1 day, or 5 months, or 5 years). Here is a sample code snippet:

```
function (var inputDate)
{
    var difference = dateNow - inputDate;
    //1 second, or 5 seconds, or 2 minutes, or 4 hours, or 1 day, or 5 months, or 5 years - I want to return the highest difference between both dates (current date and the date, which I input)
    return string difference;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479170/javascript-fuzzy-time-e-g-10-minutes-ago-thats-in-exact-seconds

Comment: Please try this. I think same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763327/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: What would you want to return if the difference is 1hour and 59 minutes? Still 1 hour?

Comment: Hello @user1950929, I would like to return 1 hour :)

Comment: @user1950929: "4 hours" seems to be the closest of his possible output values :-)

Comment: @bergi yes that would be the correct answer so probably the question is wrong :)

Comment: @Bergi, 1 second, or 5 seconds, or 2 minutes, or 4 hours, or 1 day, or 5 months, or 5 years" these were just examples :)

Comment: Is your date format really `day/month/year hours/minutes/seconds AM/PM`? Can you give us an example date in that format please.

Comment: 13/12/2013 12:36:50 pm i would suggest

Comment: @MelanciaUK, thanks for your answer! The provided forum post helped me!

Comment: I've found that post when I was looking for something similar, but using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again I'm late to the party but as @user1950292 suggests you can subtract two dates and format the difference. Something like:

```
function dateDiffString(a,b) {
    var diff = (a.getTime() - b.getTime());
    var diffs = {
        years  : Math.floor((diff) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)),
        months : Math.floor((diff) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30)),
        weeks  : Math.floor((diff) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)),
        days   : Math.floor((diff) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
        hours  : Math.floor((diff) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
        mins   : Math.floor((diff) / (1000 * 60)),
        secs   : Math.floor((diff) / (1000))
    }
    //iterate through diffs to find first number > 0
    for (var prop in diffs) {
       if(diffs.hasOwnProperty(prop) && diffs[prop] > 0){
          return diffs[prop] + " " + prop;
       }
    }
}

var today = new Date();
var anotherDay = new Date("2013 12 13,11:52:39");
alert(dateDiffString(today,anotherDay));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xuqNt/

Answer (score 0):

You can create two Date objects and substract them. Then get the days, hours, minutes, seconds of the result and choose which to output.
I have no code atm, but the Date usage is quite intuitive.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date