# Get a difference between 2 dates in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, date

Currently I'm working with an API which returns me a date(created_at) in this format:

```
Y-m-dTH-m-sZ.
```

Actually I can't find out how can I calculate a difference between this format of a date and a current date that I can receive from `new Date()`.

And the difference should be in the format like this for ex.:

```
2 hours ago, 10 days ago.
```

Is it a built in function in JS? Or how can I make this calculation and get an answer in the appropriate format?

Please help.

Comment: I always recommend `moment.js` for these sorts of things in JS. Doing it natively is quite cumbersome.

Comment: The questions you're asking are duplicates. On parsing dates: [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) On getting date difference in "friendly" format: [*Javascript fuzzy time (e.g '10 minutes ago') that's in exact seconds*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479170/javascript-fuzzy-time-e-g-10-minutes-ago-thats-in-exact-seconds).

Comment: Yes actually the same RobG.
Please read my question again. I was talking about difference in datetime formats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will work assuming dateB is after dateA, otherwise the difference will be negative and you would have to handle that.

This may be a good headstart for you, sadly there's nothing inbuilt for that, as you are trying to get a difference (which comes in miliseconds) and convert that to a unity that will vary.

Good luck, hope it's helpful.

```js
var dateA = new Date("07/06/2017");
var dateB = new Date("10/06/2017");

var difference = dateB - dateA;

var differenceUnit = "milisecond";

if(difference >= 1000) {
 difference = difference/1000;
 differenceUnit = "second";
 
 if(difference > 60) {
  difference = difference/60;
  differenceUnit = "minute";

  if(difference > 60) {
   difference = difference/60;
   differenceUnit = "hour";

   if(difference > 24) {
    difference = difference/24;
    differenceUnit = "day";
   }
  }
 }
}

difference = difference.toFixed(0);

console.log("difference is: ", difference, (difference > 1 ? differenceUnit + "s" : differenceUnit))
```