# calculating age from sysdate and birthdate using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

I'm simply trying to calc age (in years) using a birthdate variable

```
1932-04-29 00:00:00.000
```

and SYSDATETIME( ) in SQL Server, where by

```
SELECT year(Sysdatetime() - Birthdate) as Age
```

produces (surprisingly) : 1980

What did I miss? I expected to get 80!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calculating age is not as simple as it might first appear.

If you use `Datediff` you get a difference in absolute years, which is not the age.

eg

```
select DATEDIFF(yy, '1980-12-31', getdate())
```

will return 32, whereas the age of the person in question is 31.

This might be accurate enough for your purposes.
More accurate, but still wrong, you can use

```
select convert(int,DATEDIFF(d, '1933-10-31', getdate())/365.25)
```

which is right *most* of the time.

Or you can write a more complex function....

Comment: This seems to round up. Is there a way to not have it round up?

Comment: What's with dividing it by 365.25? Does this consider the leap years?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[F_GetAge]( @RefDate Datetime,@Birthdate Datetime) Returns Int as
/*
200040916 Thomas Wassermann
*/
Begin
    Declare @Alter Int
    if @RefDate>@Birthdate
    Select @Alter=(DatePart(yy,CAst(@Refdate-@Birthdate -1 as Float))-1900)
    else select @Alter=0
    Return(@Alter) 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty. Can have some errors bepending on leap years, etc.

```
-- quick and dirty age in years

declare @birthday datetime

set @birthday = '19320429'

-- this is pretty close, but could have problems with leap years, etc.
select floor(datediff(day, @birthday, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) / 365.25)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is the following:

1. both dates get converted to floats as number of days since 1900-01-01T00:00:00
2. the floats get subtracted from each other yielding the number of days between them
3. the result gets converted back to a date by adding the number of days to the base date

To correctly calculate the difference use DATEDIFF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

But there is still a problem with that. See here for a complete solution: [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate)