# Age Calculation Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)
>   [calculating age from sysdate and birthdate using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161401/calculating-age-from-sysdate-and-birthdate-using-sql-server)

In the process of some age calculations.  I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to SQL but I've been tasked with singling out persons who will turn `65yrs` old as of `31 March 2013`.  So far I'm able to calculate age based on given `DOB`, however I'm having issues singling out these persons.  I'm thinking this is a simple issue but I'm stumped, see sql statement.  Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
SELECT ip_master.ssn, ip_master.firstname, ip_master.surname, ip_master.status,

CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF (YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31'), dob) > '2013/03/31'
THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31') - 1
ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31')
END AS 'Age'

FROM test_db.dbo.ip_master ip_master
```

Comment: Singling out? Wouldn't you want a `WHERE` clause for that?

Comment: Assuming that the question refers to people turning 65 this year, no later than March 31st, `where DateAdd( year, -65, '2013-01-01' ) <= DoB and DoB <= DateAdd( year, -65, '2013-03-31' )` should do.

Answer (score 2):

Append a WHERE clause to your statement:

```
...
WHERE dob = '1948-03-31'
```

Comment: `WHERE dob = date '1948-03-31'`?, what syntax is that?

Comment: @Lamak, thanks. The syntax was updated to be ANSI-compliant.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, I knew I was over thinking this.  Was trying to use the WHERE clause on the Age column but was not sure what esle to do after it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following do? I just buried your query inside another query and applied restriction on age.

```
select * from
(
SELECT ip_master.ssn, ip_master.firstname, ip_master.surname, ip_master.status,

CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF (YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31'), dob) > '2013/03/31'
THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31') - 1
ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31')
END AS 'Age'

FROM test_db.dbo.ip_master ip_master
)
where Age >= 65
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done is correct.
For singling out you need a where clause.

```
SELECT ip_master.ssn, ip_master.firstname, ip_master.surname, ip_master.status,

CASE WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF (YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31'), dob) > '2013/03/31'
THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31') - 1
ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, dob, '2013/03/31')
END AS 'Age'
FROM test_db.dbo.ip_master ip_master
WHERE dob = '1948-03-31'
```

Comment: `CEIL` is not a valid SQL Server function. Did you mean `CEILING`?, and what would be the point of using it on an `INT` column?

Comment: yeah I meant CEILING. Is Age INT? What will be a person's age as of 31 JAN 2013?

Comment: Well, `Age` is a calculation that takes the result of `DATEDIFF`, so yes, its an `INT`. That person's age in years if it was borned on `1948-03-31` should be 64, but `DATEDIFF` will return 65

Comment: @Lamak- thanks. I dint know much about DATEDIFF

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below Query... it will work perfectly...

```
   DECLARE @CalDate datetime;
   DECLARE @CurDate datetime;
   Declare @count INT   

   SET @CalDate ='03/31/2013'
   SET @count =0
   SELECT @CurDate = DateAdd(Month, 1, @CalDate)

   SET @count = @count + datepart(dd,dateadd(dd,-1,dateadd(mm,1,cast(cast(year(@CurDate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(month(@CurDate) as varchar)+'-01' as datetime))))      

   SELECT ip_master.ssn, ip_master.firstname, ip_master.surname, ip_master.status,DATEDIFF (yy, DOB, cast(@CalDate as DateTime) + @count) - (        
    CASE SIGN (MONTH (DOB) - MONTH (cast(@CalDate as DateTime) + @count))        
     WHEN 1 THEN        
      1        
     WHEN -1 THEN         
      0         
     WHEN 0 THEN         
      CASE SIGN (DAY (DOB) - DAY (@CalDate + @count))        
       WHEN 1 THEN         
        1        
       WHEN 0 THEN        
        1       
       ELSE        
        0        
      END        
    END) as AGE into #temp
    FROM test_db.dbo.ip_master ip_master 

select * from #temp where  AGE >= 65
```

Comment: All that extra code **AND** an unnecessary temp table??? No, I"m afraid not.

Comment: @Ken White for testing purpose i have used Temp tables... and there is no extra coding... it's working for me... i have used this for many reports...