# How to calculate Age/Number of Years between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

On a project I was working on, I was required to calculate a persons age when they join the system; after looking on the internet I found various ways this could be done, but most of them had slight issues when it involved a Leap-Year.

The solution below is how I calculate number of years past / age. Hope this helps others

Comment: Can we assume that we have the birthdate?  What is the problem with leap years?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add the following method to your database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalAge] (@DiffFrom DATE, @DiffTo DATE) RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumOfYears INT
    SET @NumOfYears = (SELECT 
                         DATEDIFF(YEAR, @DiffFrom, @DiffTo) + 
                         CASE 
                           WHEN MONTH(@DiffTo) < MONTH(@DiffFrom) THEN -1 
                           WHEN MONTH(@DiffTo) > MONTH(@DiffFrom) THEN 0 
                           ELSE 
                             CASE WHEN DAY(@DiffTo) < DAY(@DiffFrom) THEN -1 ELSE 0 END 
                         END)
    IF @NumOfYears < 0
    BEGIN
        SET @NumOfYears = 0;
    END

    RETURN @NumOfYears;
END
```

You then call it in your SQL Query, similar to the following:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy 

SELECT dbo.fnCalAge(CAST('20/06/1987' AS DATE), CAST('20/06/2013' AS DATE))
```

Answer (score 8):

assuming @bDate is datetime of birthdate and @today is todays date, then...

```
 Declare @bDay Date = '31 dec 2000'
 Declare @today Date = cast(getdate() as date)
 Select datediff(Year, @bDay, @today) - 
        case When datepart(dayofYear, @today) <
                  datepart(dayofYear, @bDay) Then 1 Else 0 End
```

Comment: This doesn't always give correct results because `datepart(dayOfYear, @date)` is skewed when leap years are taken into account i.e. the extra day in the year means your birthday will be calculated a day late when after 29th Feb.

Answer (score 1):

Replace hiredate with DOB for age. Replace sysdate with your date such as to_date('28-DEC-2012') :

```
SELECT empno, ename, hiredate, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hiredate)/12)  years_of_service 
 FROM scott.emp
/
```