# sql query to get the datedifference as year(s) month(s) day(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i tried to get datediff in sql with the following query,

`SELECT DATEDIFF(MM,'05/05/2013',GETDATE())`

it's working fine but is returning results only in terms of days/months/years depending on the parameter(DD/MM/YY) passed to `DATEDIFF()` function.

is their any way to get the result as, suppose in above case 0`--years`,7`--months`,0`--days`?

thanks

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days

Comment: Note that, regardless, your chosen date format is ambiguous.  On SQL Server, please always use `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it !!

```
declare @a date
set @a='2013-05-05'

select cast(datediff(yyyy, @a, cast(getdate()as date)) as varchar(10)) + 'Years : ' 

+ cast(datediff(mm, @a, cast(getdate() as date)) as varchar(10)) + 'Months : ' 

+ cast(datediff(dd, @a, cast(getdate()as date))as varchar(10)) + 'Days'
```