# Calculate age when date month and year are in different columns in sql server

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database in which date of birth is stored in three different column as a nvarchar first column is for date second for month and third for year now how can I calculate age using these column
-Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work it out for you:

```
declare @t table (DOBYear nvarchar(19), DOBMonth nvarchar(7),
                  DOBDay nvarchar(13))
insert into @t(DOBYear,DOBMonth,DOBDay) values ('1978','05','17')

select (DATEPART(year,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - DOBYear)
    - CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(month,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < DOBMonth THEN 1
        WHEN DATEPART(month,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) = DOBMonth AND
             DATEPART(day,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < DOBDay THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END
from @t
```

Basically, you just subtract the years values, and then there are a couple of cases when that will overcount by 1, so we then adjust that value if necessary.

---

We're also relying on the fact that the `DATEPART` function returns `int`s and then data-type precedence rules will then force the `nvarchar` values to also be converted to `int`s before the comparisons occur. If you want to make the conversions explicit, you can wrap each column reference with a `CONVERT(int,<column>)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
create function dbo.dob
(
@dob datetime
)
returns datetime
as
begin
declare @out datetime
select @out = dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,convert(date,@dob),getdate())-1,@dob)
return @out
end
```

For Only Years:

```
select  convert(varchar,case    when mm > month(getdate()) 
                then datediff(yy,convert(date,yy+mm+dd),getdate())-1 
                when mm = month(getdate()) and dd>day(getdate()) 
                then datediff(yy,convert(date,yy+mm+dd),getdate())-1 
                else datediff(yy,convert(date,yy+mm+dd),getdate())end)+' Years '
 from table
```

For entire dob including days:

```
select  convert(varchar,case    when mm > month(getdate()) then datediff(yy,convert(date,yy+mm+dd),getdate())-1 
                when mm = month(getdate()) and dd>day(getdate()) then datediff(yy,convert(date,yy+mm+dd),getdate())-1 
                else datediff(yy,convert(date,yy+mm+dd),getdate())end)+' Years '+
        convert(varchar,case    when month(getdate()) = mm and dd>day(getdate())  then datediff(mm,dbo.dob(convert(date,yy+mm+dd)),getdate())-1%12 
                else datediff(mm,dbo.dob(convert(date,yy+mm+dd)),getdate())%12 end)+' Months And '+
        convert(varchar,datediff(dd,dbo.dob(yy+mm+dd),getdate())%case when year(getdate())%4 = 0 and mm > 2 then 366 else 365 end)+' Days '
from table
```

Comment: The OP has updated their question. They actually want the age, not the DOB.

Answer (score 1):

### Query:

```
  SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,[YEAR] + '-' + [MONTH] + '-' + [Day],101) AS DOB
  FROM DateOfBirth
```

### Output:

[image: DateOfBirth]

Comment: The OP has updated their question. They actually want the age, not the DOB.

Answer (score 1):

If the person was born a month previous to the actual month, or a day before or equal to today of this month, then the age is the number of years from the year of birth to the current year. If not, is the same, less 1.

```
CREATE TABLE BirthDates
(YEAR INT,
MONTH INT,
DAY INT)
```

Test data for today (2014-09-18):

```
INSERT INTO BirthDates VALUES(2013,9,19) -- 0 the frist birthday is still to come
INSERT INTO BirthDates VALUES(2013,9,18) -- 1 today is the first birthday
INSERT INTO BirthDates VALUES(2013,9,17) -- 1 the first birthday was yesterday
INSERT INTO BirthDates VALUES(2013,8,31) -- 1 the first birthday was last month
INSERT INTO BirthDates VALUES(2013,10,1) -- 0 the first birthday will be next month
```

Required query

```
SELECT B.*,
    CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE()) > B.MONTH 
               OR (MONTH(GETDATE()) = B.MONTH AND DAY(GETDATE()) >= B.DAY))
        THEN YEAR(GETDATE()) - B.YEAR 
        ELSE YEAR(GETDATE()) - B.YEAR - 1 END AS AGE
FROM BirthDates B
```

Comment: Then what about months and days

Comment: When I'm asked abut my age I say "I'm 40" I dont say "I'm 40 years, 3 months, 12 days, 7 hours, 35 minutes old". Do you say so?