# Calculating the Age from the Birthday function in SQL

Tags: sql-server, date-arithmetic

I have made a function in SQL to calculate the Age from the Birthday and it is like this:

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAge] (@birthday datetime, @date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
return datediff(SECOND, @birthday, @date) / (365.23076923074 * 24 * 60 * 60)
END
```

The birthday is of format : `1963-01-01 00:00:00.000`

My problem is that when I call the function like this :

```
SELECT dbo.GetAge(birthday, '2014-12-17 00:00:00')
  FROM [dbo].[Users]
GO
```

it says:

```
 Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.
```

BUT I call the same function with a date like :

```
SELECT dbo.GetAge(birthday, '1963-01-01 00:00:00')
      FROM [dbo].[Users]
    GO
```

I get the results..
So I don't understand what is the problem.

Pls help me and thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572110/how-to-calculate-age-in-years-based-on-date-of-birth-and-getdate

Comment: This is a very odd way to calculate the age.

Comment: I assume this must be sql server? You should only tag the relevant DBMS that you are working with. The reason for the error is because DATEDIFF returns an int and the amount of seconds between whatever value is in birthday and 2014-12-17 is greater than 2,147,483,647 which is the max value for an int.

Comment: One more thing the function works when the date is up to 2008 after that it says overflow. I think there is range in datediff by default. Do you have any idea ???

Comment: Yes I have an idea...read my comment above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate age in T-SQL with years, months, and days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all. "Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart"

```
return DATEDIFF(DAY, '1963-01-01 00:00:00', '2014-12-17 00:00:00') / (365.23076923074)
```

Comment: Dividing by the average number of days in all years is not going to produce accurate results...

Comment: Totally agree, but the question was how to fix the error, not calculate an DOB accurately to the last second

Answer (score 0):

Seems obvious..the number of seconds from a user's birthday to today is too many for whatever datatype MySQL uses for DATEDIFF.   But it's not too many from 1/1/1963.

Comment: You could use DATEDIFF(YEAR...) instead of DATEDIFF(SECOND...), and then you wouldn't have to do the extra math "/ (365.23076923074 * 24 * 60 * 60)"

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to use a less precise `datepart`, i.e. `minute` instead of `second`.

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAge] (@birthday datetime, @date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
return datediff(MINUTE, @birthday, @date) / (365.23076923074 * 24 * 60)
END
```

OR `hour`

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAge] (@birthday datetime, @date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
return datediff(HOUR, @birthday, @date) / (365.23076923074 * 24)
END
```

OR `DAY`

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAge] (@birthday datetime, @date datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
return datediff(DAY, @birthday, @date) / (365.23076923074)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `DATEDIFF(year, @birthday, @date)`?  You only want the whole number of years, right?

Comment: Because this doesn't work. DATEDIFF counts the number of date parts crossed. It does NOT caluclate the difference. Consider that the following returns 1, obviously this is only 1 day and not a year. select DATEDIFF(year, '2013-12-31', '2014-01-01')

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks, I did not know that.  Well I guess this question unsurprisingly has been answered many times already anyway...marking as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your birthday to a date before sending it off.

```
SELECT dbo.GetAge(birthday, select cast('1963-01-01 00:00:00.000' as date))
  FROM [dbo].[Users]
GO
```