# How to calculate age from date of birth in years.months format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query but it returns only years, but I need months too. Below is the query I have written:

```
select cast(datediff(DAY, '2000-06-01 10:00:01', getDate() -1) / (365.23076923074) as varchar) as 'Age'
```

Comment: can you please provide one example, exactly what output you expect.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days

Comment: I want out put like 14.11 where 14 is years and 11 is months

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @DateOfBirth date= '1999-06-1'

Select AgeYears=DATEDIFF(year,@DateOfBirth ,getdate())- CASE WHEN MONTH(getdate())*100+DAY(getdate())<MONTH(@DateOfBirth)*100+DAY(@DateOfBirth) then 1 else 0 end
    ,AgeMoanths=(DATEDIFF(month,@DateOfBirth,getdate())  - CASE WHEN DAY(getdate())<DAY(@DateOfBirth) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) % 12
    ,Agedays=DATEDIFF (day,dateadd(month,(DATEDIFF(month,@DateOfBirth,getdate())  - CASE WHEN DAY(getdate())<DAY(@DateOfBirth) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  ,@DateOfBirth) ,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this

```
Declare @dateofbirth datetime
Declare @currentdatetime datetime
Declare @years varchar(40)
Declare @months varchar(30)
Declare @days varchar(30)
set @dateofbirth='1986-03-15' 
set @currentdatetime = getdate()--current datetime
select @years=datediff(year,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)-- To find Years
select @months=datediff(month,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)-(datediff(year,@dateofbirth,@currentdatetime)*12)
-- To Find Months
select @days=datepart(d,@currentdatetime)-datepart(d,@dateofbirth)-- To Find Days
select @years  +' years,   ' +@months +' months,   '+@days   +' days' asYearMonthDay
```

output would be

```
29 years, 2 months, -10 days
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db5/9)

**Update**

Single line query would be

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(YEAR,'2000-06-01 10:00:01',GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '.' + CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2000-06-01 10:00:01',GETDATE())-(DATEDIFF(YEAR,'2000-06-01 10:00:01',GETDATE())*12) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS Age
```

Comment: I need single line  sql  as i need it to add as subquery

Comment: I just gave sample. You can make it single line query

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @setdate datetime
            ,@current datetime
SET @setdate = '20000601'
SET @current = GETDATE()
SELECT Years=DATEDIFF(year,@setdate,@current ) 
                      - CASE WHEN MONTH(@current )*100+DAY(@current )<MONTH(@setdate)*100+DAY(@setdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          , Months=( DATEDIFF(month,@setdate,@current )
                          - CASE WHEN DAY(@current )<DAY(@setdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  % 12
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db5/8)**

And to get the output in format like 14.11 try this:

```
DECLARE @setdate datetime
            ,@current datetime
SET @setdate = '20000601'
SET @current = GETDATE()
SELECT CAST((DATEDIFF(year,@setdate,@current ) 
                      - CASE WHEN MONTH(@current )*100+DAY(@current )<MONTH(@setdate)*100+DAY(@setdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS varchar(10))
          +'.' + CAST((( DATEDIFF(month,@setdate,@current )
                          - CASE WHEN DAY(@current )<DAY(@setdate) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )  % 12) AS varchar(10))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db5/19)**

Comment: What would adding the days to the query look like? Seems to me doing so may require a lot of extra logic, with the different number of days in different months (plus Feb, putting different days in the same month and year!) - especially in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was :

```
 select convert(varchar(05),cast(datediff(DAY, '2000-06-01 10:00:01', getDate() -1) / (365.23076923074) as int))+'.'+convert(varchar(05),cast(datediff(MONTH, '2000-06-01 10:00:01', getDate() -1) % (12) as int)) as Age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @DOB varchar(20)
Set @DOB ='1989-12-15 10:00:01' SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Years' 
+ CAST(DATEDIFF(MONTH,@DOB,GETDATE())-(DATEDIFF(YEAR,@DOB,GETDATE())*12) AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'Months' 
+ CAST(DATEDIFF(dd,@DOB,GETDATE())-(DATEDIFF(year,@DOB,GETDATE())*1461/4) AS VARCHAR(10)) +'Days'
```