# SQL Select query using current date time to get the users ages?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to find age, for example, between 20 to 30 from my table from the current system date.

Below is my table details:

```
GivenName           DOB
  Raj       1950-06-06 00:00:00.000
  Rahul     1951-01-06 00:00:00.000
  Mohan     1952-11-09 00:00:00.000
  khan      1953-07-24 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time. Data type for DOB column?

Comment: sql server 2008. @jarlh

Comment: @Matt Gibson: You are right. And dotjoe's answer there looks better than any answer given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for example, between 20 to 30

Use [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
SELECT Age = DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()),
       Between20_30 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30
                      Then 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
FROM dbo.Table1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98134/2/0)

If you want to filter by persons who are between 20 and 30 use a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

---

Since `DATEDIFF` ist not precise(treats the month difference between 12/31 and 01/01 as one month), if that's an issue you could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57720/284240) approach.

Comment: Watch out with using DATEDIFF. The age calculation will not be very precise this way. The function rounds off.

Comment: I need those record, who have age 20 to 30 years.

Comment: @Tom: god point, if that's an issue he could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/57720/284240) approach.

Comment: @zahed: then use `WHERE DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30`. I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: SELECT Age = DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()),
       Between20_30 = where DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30
                       FROM Table_RegistrationInfo.. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'. Getting error..

Comment: @zahed: `WHERE` comes always after the `FROM` clause. So: `SELECT ... FROM tbl WHERE DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30`

Comment: SELECT Age = DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()),
       Between20_30 = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30
                      Then 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
FROM Table_RegistrationInfo WHERE DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30.  I got it. Check once my query.

Comment: Please can you give vote for my question. @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 0):

```
select GivenName,Age = DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate())
FROM [dbo].[AgeCalc] where DATEDIFF(year, DOB, GetDate()) BETWEEN 20 AND 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `DATEDIFF`. When using `DATEDIFF(year, ...)` it is only the year part of the dates that is being considered. So it wouldn't matter which birthday exactly and you'd consider people 20 years old who are not yet full twenty years old.

Today `2015-12-26` you would want persons born between `1984-12-17` till `1995-12-16`.

- `1984-12-17` (today minus 31 years plus one day) means the person gets 31 tomorrow
- `1995-12-16` (today minus 20 years) means the person just got 20 today.

So:

```
select *
from persons
where convert(varchar, dob, 102) 
        between convert(varchar, dateadd(day, 1, dateadd(year, -31, getdate())), 102)
            and convert(varchar, dateadd(year, -20, getdate()), 102);
```

(I must  admit though that I am too lazy to think the February 29 thing through now.)

Comment: Can you update answer according to above my table details.

Comment: All I see in your table details is that the date of birth column is called DOB. I used that. So what else should I consider?

Comment: And here is a SQL fiddle illustrating that `DATEDIFF(year, ...)` is not appropriate for calculating the age: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/3740.

Comment: Please take above my question example.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. You gave an example with a table containing GivenName and DOB and four records; I have given you a query to select persons between 20 and 30 years old from it. What else do you want? Have you tried my query and it doesn't work for you? If so, in what sense doesn't it work for you?