# Calculating age at time of an event in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

What is the best way to calculate age based on an event? I'm trying to look for individuals based on their age when an event took place? I'm relative new to SQL and the dates functions, I can't wrap my head around.

Example:

```
ID        Name         Age   DOB          AdmitDate
1234      John Smith   61    1960-07-15   2019-10-22
```

How can I can calculate whose age was 59 at the time  of admit date?

Comment: For accuracy, I recommend this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1572938/9947159

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, [DOB], AdmitDate) / 365 You can use this as a derived column, put into a temp table, and from that temp table, add your WHERE clause to find people who are 59.

Answer (score 1):

[DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) provides the function to do this.

e.g.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF ( yy , '1960-07-15' , '2019-10-22' )
```

Comment: What does `SELECT DATEDIFF ( yy , '2019-12-31' , '2020-01-01' )` return?

Comment: @SalmanA yes this doesn't work for my issue.

Comment: @SalmanA Why would you close my question when I clearly don't have an answer to this?

Comment: @Leonardo see the question I linked to. If your problem is different, edit the question with explanation and I'll re-open.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from  yourtable 
where  DATEDIFF( year , CAST(DOB AS datetime), CAST(AdmitDate AS datetime)) >= 59
```

Try this

Comment: This sort of works. But it will return 59 for ANY date in 1960.

Comment: It'll return 1 year if the dates are 2019-12-31 and 2020-01-01 (the actual age is just 1 day).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57599/3943730 Check this link to calculate accurate date difference