# How can I get a time period between two datetimes as a timespan in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I know that SQL Server's `DATEDIFF` will calculate the difference between two `datetime` values in a chosen unit - hours, days, etc.

But I want to get the difference between two `datetime` values more like .Net's `DateTimeOffset` e.g. more like a date format: years, months, days, hours, minutes.

I don't know if SQL Server 2016 has any equivalent type, or built in functions to do this? Or would I have to roll some custom logic?

Comment: You mean like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)? If not, what *are* you asking? Sample data and expected results help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu yes same question but I am asking if it can be done in a simple query - or whether T-SQL is required. If it is, this question is probably a dupe.

Comment: You want a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTimeOffset`.  
The first is a period of time, which is what you get in c# (or any other .Net language for that matter) when subtracting a `DateTime` value from another `DateTime` value, while the second is a `DateTime` for a specific time zone.

Comment: There is no `timespan` data type in SQL Server, no. You would have to use something like the above to achieve this in T-sQL. You *could* implement a CLR function, however, you would still be unable to return a `timespan` data type.

Comment: I've implemented `timespan` as a CLR data type. It was a fun exercise and I could see it being useful. Not too difficult from what I remember.

Comment: Unless someone wants to provide a CLR-based answer (I'd be very interested) I will vote to close this as a dupe.